# Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, postgresql, osx-lion

I recently upgraded to OSX 10.7, at which point my rails installation completely borked when trying to connect to the psql server.   When I do it from the command line using

```
psql -U postgres
```

it works totally fine, but when I try to run the rails server or console with the same username and password, I get this error

```
...activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:950:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Permission denied (PGError) 
Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any ideas what might be going on would be super helpful!  Thanks!

Comment: This also hit someone in my office; we had a similar problem with getting the wrong binary, an additional problem with trying to connect to domain sockets in a different directory with different permissions, and it looks like the upgrade ate all the data on the local database. Fortunately this was just a development box, so it's not a huge deal, but mildly obnoxious. :)

Comment: I hit this one myself today and remembered reading your question yesterday. Good to see @John Wang has come out and explained it :)

Answer (score 290, accepted):

It's a PATH issue. Mac OSX Lion includes Postgresql in the system now. If you do a `which psql` you'll likely see `usr/bin/psql` instead of `usr/local/bin/psql` which is HomeBrew's correct one. If you run `brew doctor` you should get a message stating that you need to add `usr/local/bin` to the head of your PATH env variable.

Editing your .bash_profile or .profile, or whichever shell you're using and adding:
`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

as the first export for the `PATH` then either quit you shell session or source your file with `source ~/.bash_profile` and it should now be OK again.

Comment: This fixed it. You can also edit /etc/paths and make sure /usr/local/bin is on the top

Comment: Also, note that if you installed the pg gem BEFORE fixing your path, it will use the wrong psql.  If so, uninstall the pg gem and then reinstall it (gem uninstall pg && gem install pg).

Comment: Is this for homebrew? Ports seems to put it in:
/opt/local/lib/postgresql91
So make sure you use
export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin:$PATH

Comment: My path was reporting correctly, but Troy's solution of uninstalling the pg gem, then letting bundler reinstall did the trick for me.

Comment: Just to clarify - it looks as if you are best to setup your path correctly, then uninstall/reinstall the pg gem

Comment: Troy's comment worked for me. Running Mountain Lion, and had just installed homebrew's postgres.

Comment: Also note for the Python users; you have to reinstall your PostgreSQL driver (that is likely to be psycopg2) after you fix your path issue explained above. To do that: `pip uninstall psycopg2 && pip install psycopg2` within your virtualenv.

Comment: uninstall pg gem? I have installed rubymine and postgres and induction. This error comes up when trying to connect to postgres through induction. How can I uninstall pg gem?

Answer (score 90):

For those of you who are interested, I pieced together the solution.  All I needed was to add

```
host: localhost
```

to the database.yml for my environment and all was gravy.

Comment: be careful with this: This setting changes the access from the domain socket to a TCP connection. While it probably works, you might lose a bit of performance and usable ports on your machine which can be a problem depending on your setup. The solution provided by John is correct.

Comment: 'gem uninstall pg' (choose all versions), then 'bundle' again to install the pg version from your Gemfile worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Dave G, this worked for me too. I installed 10.7.3 update and rake db:migrate complained. This fixed it.

Comment: This worked for me too. However i left the password and the username blank.

Comment: I'd imagine this would work because it forces a TCP/IP connection.

Answer (score 46):

I had this very problem with Mountain Lion but the only thing that worked for me was [this fix](http://www.iainlbc.com/2011/10/osx-lion-postgres-could-not-connect-to-database-postgres-after-homebrew-installation/):

Check where the actual target is:

```
sudo find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432
```

I needed to create this directory:

```
mkdir /var/pgsql_socket/
```

Then using the result from the find above create this symlink:

```
ln -s /private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/
```

I suspect that for most people on Mountain Lion you can just create the dir and do the symlink and not waste time doing the find unless the symlink doesn't work.

PS - my PostgreSQL was installed through the official installer.

Comment: I have a feeling it might be it for me but can't make it work. I'm getting this : 
ln: /var/pgsql_socket/: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I ran into that too. Added extra step to answer.

Comment: Bless you Ben. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

If the problem persists past changing the path (as it did for me), also try this...

```
gem pristine pg
```

It appears that the problem (partially) lies in the pg gem itself.  When it builds, it figures  out where the domain socket should be.  If you change the location of the domain socket after the fact it doesn't seem to take effect until you rebuild the gem.

Comment: This worked for me, even after I fixed the PATH and reinstalled the pg gem without pristine.

Answer (score 15):

For those who installed direct from the official installer, just adding the host to the command works with no path changes:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and was having problems making John Wang's solution work. As Darren noted there's an issue with the pg gem. To get it work I needed to:

```
gem uninstall pg
```

Then reinstall.

Which got it working.

Comment: I had to run this twice...odd. I did uninstall pg then bundle install and it failed. Then just did gem install pg and it worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well, but I had installed postgres myself (not with homebrew). If that's the case, you need to find the old path to psql (which may be /usr/local/bin, but for me was /usr/local/pgsql/bin) and prepend that to your $PATH.

(before)
`which psql` => /usr/bin/psql

(fix)
export PATH=/usr/local/psql/bin:$PATH

(after)
`which psql' => /usr/local/psql/bin

John Wang's suggestion to `source ~/.bash_rc` afterward you add that to your bash_rc is golden.

Answer (score 3):

Is this for homebrew? Ports seems to put it in:

```
/opt/local/lib/postgresql91
```

So make sure you use export

```
PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin:$PATH
```

Mac ports issue:
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/30125

Answer (score 1):

I'm not happy with the most upvoted answers as they are either OS-user specific or remap Postgres to use TCP instead of domain sockets, as pointed out by @pilif.  I've seen another solution that involves re-ordering the default paths at the system level to check Brew's path before a core system path, but this seems hazardous as it could affect all other application name-collisions like this one.

[This site](http://nextmarvel.net/blog/2011/09/brew-install-postgresql-on-os-x-lion/) details a solution my coworker found.  It comes down to executing a single shell script that will

1. back up the Postgres 8.4 files in a separate directory
2. symlink the brew's installation of Postgres in place

This comes with the caveat that the system default Postgres is whatever brew has installed, so you have to make a judgment call about whether that's right for you.  I don't see myself needing Postgres 8.4 specifically over 9.x, but YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution that worked for me is resetting the postmaster file by deleting it. Simply run:

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

It's worth checking the log for errors which you can find here:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

The error message I was having was:

```
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 161) running in data directory 
"/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

Everything worked great afterwards.

Comment: I had the issue only from the command line. Removing the file  /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the server didn't start because of wrong shared memory settings. At first I was confused because there were several postgres processes running, but those were standard system processes. Look for `postmaster` processes!

All I needed to do was to [change the shared memory settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615153/235297). Fiddling around with the path settings wasn't needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you like a permanent change in your **$PATH** try this:

```
defaults write $HOME/.MacOSX/environment PATH "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin"
```

this will rewrite your `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the host of your database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Rails, but adding the following to *database.yml* worked for me:

```
host: localhost

port: 5432
```

Not sure why Rails defaults to domain sockets instead of TCP, while PostgreSQL does not set up domain sockets by default.

Answer (score 0):

My PostgreSQL is installed in /Library/PostgreSQL so that /usr/var stuff didn't work for me.

It appears that Woz is correct because everytime I close my macbook pro's lid it crashes...
Here is what worked post-crash for me:

```
sudo su postgres -c "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_ctl -m fast -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data restart"
```