# Postgresql macports cannot connect problem

Tags: macos, postgresql, macports

Im trying to run createuser command on a recently installed postgresql90-server instance with macports and Im getting this error.

createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

never the less If I run psql it connects to the database with no problem, what could be the problem?

Comment: Well aparently I needed to set the host with the -h flag, which to me point of view is just dumb!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem with Lion because it (or maybe xcode) comes with a version of postgreSQL installed on it.

You can find the solution in this other post:

[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing `DATABASES.HOST` value to `/tmp/` (for some reason after updating OS X to M-Lion postgresql changed socket folder to `/tmp/`).