# What version of PostgreSQL does Lion ship with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql, osx-lion, rails-postgresql

I have just read "Mac OSX Lion includes Postgresql" ([Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)).

Assuming I buy a brand new MacBook Pro running Lion, what version of PostgreSQL will be installed by default?  If I am doing Rails development work for an app that's going onto Heroku, does this mean I don't need to bother with installing PostgreSQL via homebrew or the binary installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With non-Server version you will have only a client of PostgreSQL. So, you will need to install PostgreSQL server locally from MacPorts (7.4, 8.0-8.4, 9.0, 9.1) or Homebrew (9.0.4).

Comment: Great!  Thanks for answering my question so quickly!  Do you know if the homebrew install will work without changing anything or should I be following this: http://tammersaleh.com/posts/installing-postgresql-for-rails-3-1-on-lion  ?

Comment: Actually, I prefer MacPorts with `/opt/local` in $PATH. So, of course, you will need to add Homebrew's `/usr/local/bin` path to your $PATH variable, that's just a needed configuration of your system to work with 3rd party package managers. Nothing special.