# PostgreSQL and OS X Lion Permission Issues .bash_profile

Tags: postgresql, bash, osx-lion

**SET UP:**
I have OS X Lion 10.7.2 installed (not upgraded)
I bought the laptop (no software upgrade)
I have Version 4.2 (4D199) installed

My .bash_profile says the following:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

When I type 'which psql' I get:

```
/usr/bin/psql
```

I have read this post on fixing the postresql [Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion) and in this article it says that the when you type `which psql` you should be getting:

```
usr/local/bin/psql
```

I'm not getting it. What am I doing wrong?

---

### **UPDATE - FOR ANYONE**

If anyone has the same set up as me do the following: Read this link https://plus.google.com/114301087219148980063/posts/VHmzi63jCJK I have copied and pasted what this person has wrote:

If you've installed or upgraded to Lion, you probably noticed that it now comes with a partial PostgreSQL 9.0.4 installation. Replacing shoddy MySQL with proper beardy Unix database software is no doubt a good thing, but you will quickly notice that the actual PostgreSQL server is missing, as it's part of the "server" version of Lion and not included in the regular flavor. So how do you get your PostgreSQL development server back?

1. **Do not buy Lion Server** http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/os-x-lion-server/id444376097?mt=12. For £35 this should get you the official build of the server part of PostgreSQL, along with a lot of other stuff you most likely don't need. Save the cash and the diskspace.
2. **Do not install the official PostgreSQL Mac package from EnterpriseDB** http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload. It's nice of them to provide one, but it's currently not working with Lion (minor user creation issues - although there is a workaround).
3. **Do not Build from source** http://cambhlumbulunk.blogspot.com/2011/07/os-x-lion-2-postgresql-as-default.html. This will work, but leave you with a clutter of files in /usr/local that conflict with system files unless you're taking special care.
4. **Do `brew install postgresql`**. Yes, this is almost the same as 3., but the result can be easily removed or updated later. Plus you get nice setup instructions at the end about how to create a database and launch postgres at login. Homebrew [Link](https://brew.sh/) will also help you set up your environment so that things that require PostgreSQL headers and includes to build (like psycopg2) can find them without any messing around.

**FINAL NOTE:**

1. You must have brew installed first.
2. After you have installed brew then you can install postgresql `brew install postgresql`
3. The installation provides EXCELLENT notes for creating your initial DB and starting/stop PostgresSQL for OS X Lion. **Save the notes and do the initial create DB**
4. Once you have at this point you can create a db. i.e. `psql -d stuff`

For the longest time I kept wondering why the initial OS X Lion PostgreSQL was not working and  it comes down to it's missing the server version. Anyone else banging their heads on this I hope this reference material helps.

Comment: so `/usr/bin/psql` is wrong? Please edit your post to include the path you are expecting for psql. Good luck.

Comment: excellent update. You can post your update as an answer and accept it,  which will benefit your rep-score. (I think you have to wait 24 hrs to accept your own answer). Good luck.

Comment: What do you get if you type `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @BenHocking I updated the post awhile back. I use `brew` to get everything up and running.

Comment: If using Server, see http://rubyist-journal.com/2011/10/27/fix-postgres-permission-denied-issue-on-osx-lion/, which says to put /usr/local/bin at the top of /etc/paths.

Answer (score 1):

*.bash_profile* is read on *login* (if you're using *bash* as your *login* shell or if you force its execution with the *--login* option). 
Did you try to log off and on after you've modified the initialization file (*.bash_profile* will not be read if you just open a new terminal window)?
You may add the path settings to your *.bashrc* file too (it's read whenever an *interactive shell* is spawned).

Did you check if *psql* is actually available in */usr/local/bin* ?

Comment: When I type `which psql` I get `/usr/local/bin` and according to this article this is a problem for OS X Lion users because they cannot access `psql`. If I just type `psql` in the command line I get `could not connect to server: Permission denied` . I'm sort of confused on what my ideal `.bash_profile` should be. I'm worried I might be mixing up my paths or something.