# Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7.3 Lion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion, pg

I have the issue described in:
[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)
but didn't get it solved.

The Postgres application generating the error is at `/usr/bin/psql`,
but the correct one is at 
`/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/psql`.

When I add the later to my path in `.bash_profile` (or even in `/etc/paths`), uninstall and install the PG gem, then I still receive the error:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1161:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Permission denied (PG::Error) Is the server running locally and accepting
```

I tried it several times, also with the option:

```
-- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_config
```

Any idea?

---

EDIT:

After reading through more posts (like http://www.iainlbc.com/2011/10/osx-lion-postgres-could-not-connect-to-database-postgres-after-homebrew-installation),
I just did the following:

```
sudo ln -s /private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/
```

And it worked. I don't know at all why. Do I have two installations of Postgres? Where is the app laying behind the `/usr/bin/psql` file?

Comment: OSX 10.7 comes with PostgreSQL (9.0.5) client libraries and command-line utilities. OSX 10.7 Server has the PostgreSQL server, too.

Answer (score 2):

After running `find / -name .s.PGSQL.5432 -ls`, I noticed that the result was:

47366187        0 srwxrwxrwx    1 postgres         wheel                   0 Dec  3 15:15 /private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

Note that the PGSQL socket file is `/private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`

Using your suggestion above (but modifying it a bit), I did this:

```
sudo ln -s /private/tmp /var/pgsql_socket
```

Restarted terminal and it worked.