# Postgresql adapter (pg): could not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql, pg

I get this error every this I run my Rails app (It **cannot connect to my local Postgresql**)

```
/Users/leonardo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/
active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': 
could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::Error)
   Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I'm using [**Postgres.app**](http://postgresapp.com/) that it's correctly running.

If I run

```
$ psql
```

I can login properly  to Postgresql console.

```
$ which psql
 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql
```

***Gemfile***

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem "pg"
```

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: leonardo
  password: 
  database: zapping
  port: 5432
```

**Postgresql** (Console)

```
$ psql
leonardo=# \l
```

[image]

Comment: can you try add `host: localhost` to your database.yml ? (based on that answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10793186/919641)

Comment: If you add it in "answers" I will marked as accepted

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Try adding `host: localhost` to your database.yml. (Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10793186/919641)

Answer (score 26):

Your `Pg` gem was compiled against the PostgreSQL libpq pre-installed in Mac OS X and you're using the `psql` that you installed in a newer version, or vice versa.

This can be worked around by specifying a TCP/IP connection, by adding `localhost` to `database.yml`, but it's better to compile the `Pg` gem against the `libpq` for the server you're actually running. To do that, you should be able to set the `PATH` environment variable to the folder with the correct `pg_config` in it before compiling. In your case that'll be somewhere within `Postgres.app`.

Comment: Craig, can you please elaborate this one? Where and which env. variable should I set exactly?

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me fix it. The steps I took were simple: 1) `gem uninstall pg`, 2) `bundle install`, done.

Comment: Perfect answer, and although updating `database.yml` works too, I think this is probably the best and most correct solution for this problem. If you've, say, installed Postgresql via Homebrew *after* installing `pg`, you might see this error. Then follow @haslo's instructions above.

Answer (score 25):

If it does not work even after adding `host: localhost`, remove the `postmaster.pid`

`rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Comment: This solved the problem that I had. 

Even though running `brew services start postgresql` said it was successful, running `ps x | grep postgres` showed no server running. 

I followed the steps here (which include removing the `postmaster.pid`) and it solved the problem for me: https://coderwall.com/p/zf-fww/postgres-on-osx-with-homebrew-not-running-after-osx-crash

Comment: This works if your computer crashes and you do a forced shutdown but postgres wasn't properly terminated, sometimes the pid file will get stuck there... removing it helps get it going again.

Comment: No no no do NOT do this! It's *only* OK if you verify that *no* postgres processes are still running. It should rarely if ever be necessary; it can only arise if some other process happens to get assigned the pid the postmaster had.

Comment: Should be okay for local postgres connections.

Comment: This was my problem, I don't understand the reply above from @CraigRinger what is the harm in this? It was immediately rebuilt for me by the service when it finally started.

Comment: @DavidGreco `postmaster.pid` serves as an interlock that stops one postgres from starting while another is still writing to the database file. If you remove it, you might have two (or more) postgres processes writing to the same database without coordinating with each other, resulting in massive database corruption. So *do not do it* unless you have made *absolutely sure* no other postgres processes are surviving and accessing the same data directory.

Answer (score 11):

you should add `host: localhost` to your db config...

Comment: Im not sure why i get downvoted, I answered 5 minutes before! the accepted answer (which has the same solution like my post)?

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I had to add `host: db`.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issue. One of the comments here helped me fix the issue.

> Thanks, this answer helped me fix it. The steps I took were simple: 1)
>   gem uninstall pg, 2) bundle install, done. – haslo Dec 3 '13 at 20:27

```
gem uninstall pg
bundle install
```

Comment: This fixed it for me. I had uninstalled/reinstall postgres and the gem needed to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on a Mac. Turns out that the psql I had on my path wasn't working correctly. 
Try launching psql by typing:

```
~/projects/some_project/project-rails$ psql
  psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

If you see this, it indicates the psql binary on your path is attempting to connect using socket and unable to do so (for whatever reason). Since I had already downloaded [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org) and it was connecting fine, I knew it wasn't an issue with the server.

*Fixed it* by adding the right version of pgsql to my PATH:

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH
```

Now psql (and rails) are happy!

Comment: re-installation of the pg gem were also required

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue. You have to actually run / start postgres. Postgres must have stopped running on my computer recently, so I had to make sure it's running by starting the postgres server

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Then the following commands (which were causing me the same error you had) all worked:

```
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate
bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 6):

Since This was the first post that appeared in my search result, I have decided to post the updated fix for this. Since none of the above suggestion worked for me.

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

It upgraded postgresql data and moved my old version. I was on 9.6 instead of 10.4

Found the solution [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75214/postgresql-not-running-on-mac)

Answer (score 5):

find / -name 'postgresql.conf'

netstat -an | grep 5432 **# => /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432**

vi /Users/admin/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres93/var/postgresql.conf

**FROM:** unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'

**TO:** unix_socket_directories = '/var/pgsql_socket'

sudo mkdir /var/pgsql_socket

sudo chmod 777 /var/pgsql_socket

Comment: This solution, ultimately in my case, would have fixed my issue with Rails not being able to start. I went a little different approach on the way to realizing this. I actually created a symlink as described in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466146/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-3-lion#)

Answer (score 2):

For heroku this is all you need.

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql

production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 host: localhost
 # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
 # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
 pool: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the problem that the postgres app wasn't running on my mac...

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, I had different versions of postgresql. This problem has been solved when I tried `brew switch postgresql 9.5.5` (I don't think version number matters at this point)

```
$ brew switch postgresql 9.5.5
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.5
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.2
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.3
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.5
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.4
```

All data will be gone away, by the way. I guess there's a brew command for doing this without switching version, which I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on OS High sierra 10.13
I followed the instructions from this website I downloaded version 10.4
ref: https://postgresapp.com/

Then I added this to bash profile:
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/10.4/bin:$PATH

re start terminal.

Open new window terminal and then type: psql -U postgres

after that you will see this message:
psql (10.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the `/etc/hosts` file changed and didn't have this crucial entry: `127.0.0.1              localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - when I ran `psql` command in terminal I still got the same error, so that told me that it wasn't a problem with the pg gem and I should check the postgres setup itself. So I checked the postgres logs - in my case they were located at `/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log` and I saw the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.66.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres
```

So knowing the exact error helped me resolve the issue, in my case based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54180353/5725619) I ran

```
brew switch icu4c 66.1
```

which resolved the issue after restarting postgres:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a problem connecting if I set the hostname to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. The PostgreSQL client library seems to treat those as special cases, looking for the UNIX socket instead of the TCP port.

I was able to solve my problem by setting the hostname to `localhost.`. The trailing period makes it not hit the special case, and makes it work for me.

Comment: Adding this because I've run into it twice myself, and I couldn't remember the original answer the second time. I couldn't find any other pertinent question to attach it to.