# PG::Connection bad error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using rails 4.2.6 and ruby 2.3 to create an application .The database I am using is postgresql . When I am running the `rails s` and going to localhost:3000 then the error PG::Connection bad is showing . how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you entered the password in database.yml in your rails app?

Comment: can you connect to the database outside of rails?  using psql for instance on a command line? Have you double checked the password?  have you reviewed other stackoverflow answers?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225038/postgresql-adapter-pg-could-not-connect-to-server

Comment: generally you may want to create your rails app using `rails new appName --database=postgresql`. This would create the right config files for you.

Answer (score 2):

could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

when you display such an error, postgresql server is already running.

Check PG status;

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
```

Response;

```
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 377)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.1/bin/postgres "-D" "/usr/local/var/postgres"
```

Kill the process by pid

```
kill 377
```

Comment: Actually, when I got that error, postgresql server was NOT running: `pg_ctl: no server running`. In that case, all you need is `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`. (On a mac with `homebrew`).

Answer (score 0):

If your postgresql server is running fine, your configuration in rails might be not well set here is an exemple:

file in config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
  username: your_pg_username
  password: your_pg_password
  port: your_pg_server_port_5432_by_default
  database: your_databasename
```