# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib error running php after installing node with brew on Mac

Tags: php, node.js, macos, homebrew

I installed node using homebrew (Mojave), afterwards php stoped working and if I try to run `php -v` I get this error:

```
php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried to uninstall both node and icu4c but the problem persists

Comment: Did you also install php from Homebrew? Did you try to reinstall php?

Comment: For posterity: uninstall/reinstall yarn/node seems to do the trick.

Comment: according to my understanding, this happens when you've mismatch version dependencies. in my case, "brew upgrade" command fixed my issues.

please correct me, if i'm wrong in any way.

Comment: While I was getting this, the problem was that `/usr/local/opt/icu4c` didn't exist, and `brew reinstall icu4c` gave me a bunch of "permission denied" issues for the icu4c dir. So I `sudo rm -rf  /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c` and `brew reinstall icu4c`, and everything worked.

Comment: I have a weird situation (using High Sierra on an outdated machine) but this occurred after I updated PHP to 7.2 (or tried to). My solution was to reinstall node from a download. Homebrew isn't reliable once you're out of the range of MacOSs supported by Apple, I find.

Comment: just running `brew upgrade` helped me

Comment: I came here due to problem with yarn which came from homebrew. None of the mentioned solution work, and finally I fixed it by installing yarn via nvm

Comment: Lots of outdated solutions here, unfortunately. I wrote about what I was able to do that solved it. Short version: Create a custom `new-tap` so you can `extract` the old formula and reinstall it from source, then manually symlink the new version over - https://gist.github.com/romellem/dcaba2d57d246420f600b7cfeb4b0cdd

Comment: Adding to @sh6210, I had to do brew upgrade -f to force the upgrade past an issue of a non-empty directory not deleting, but end result was same: fixed.

Comment: Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67488727/529403), replacing the version number with your needs.

Comment: This can happen if you run a different version of node (e.g. in an IDE) to that which created the `node_modules`

Comment: This worked for me `brew reinstall php@8.3` // replace your version here

Comment: The steps outlined in this blog helped me achieve this https://mikebian.co/installing-an-old-homebrew-package/

Answer (score 1025, accepted):

> Update - As stated in some of the comments, running `brew cleanup` could possibly fix this error, if that alone doesn't fix it, you might try upgrading individual packages or all your brew packages.

I just had this same problem. Upgrading Homebrew and then cleaning up worked for me. This error likely showed up for me because of a mismatch in package versions. None of the above solutions resolved my error, but running the following homebrew commands did.

> **Caution** - This will upgrade all your brew packages, including, but not limited to PHP. If you only want to upgrade specific packages make sure to be specific.

```
brew upgrade icu4c

brew upgrade // or upgrade all packages
```

and finally

```
brew cleanup
```

Comment: This worked for me after running `brew link npm....` command which seems to have borked composer, php, etc.

Comment: @VincentTang what has npm to do with it? Where did you run this?

Comment: I think this is not a good idea for those that have environment with two versions of PHP like me. Also, brew upgrade will upgrade your PHP version and this is not necessary good if your goal is not to upgrade your PHP, but solve a library error.

Comment: Good for me! After a Rails problem.

Comment: @mpoletto It is a good idea to stay current (for security) and homebrew provides tools to set an older version of one library without putting the entire environment, your users, and your system at risk. If you want to use an older php, it should not come at the cost of throwing the entire system in a time capsule.

Comment: @AbandonedCart I was thinking in a developing environment, only in my machine... Imagine that I have two totally distinct systems in two production environments, one with PHP 5.6 and another with PHP 7.2. I am using my machine to develop sometimes to system 5.6 as another times to 7.2.

Comment: @mpoletto Nothing you have presented is a reason why my suggestion is not possible. You really shouldn't have production systems that are intentionally outdated without good cause.

Comment: Clever but didn't work for me, on the other hand a reinstall of php7.2 also didn't work on my system so that's probably the reason why ...

Comment: I wouldn't do this because `brew upgrade` will upgrade *all* your brew outdated packages, instead, probably only do `brew upgrade npm` or a specific package, not all.

Comment: @xgMz You’re right about this. For me, I didn’t care if I was updating all my packages, but for someone that doesn’t want to, then that’s probably not great. I added a note to my solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Leland 's answer below is what was needed for me even after brew cleanup and brew upgrade of specific package. Switching the package manually worked.

Comment: This worked before I even ran brew cleanup.  In my case the error didn't occur until I tried running an n98 command (magento cli) through crontab.  This helped.

Comment: I saw `brew upgrade` and disliked immediately.

Comment: I did this and ended up with half a day of package cleanup to get my development environment back. Not a good idea for most cases.

Comment: @Joey I'm sorry to hear that! I know this solution helped me and has helped others. If there is anything I should include in this answer to make sure that doesn't happen to someone else, let me know!

Comment: For me, only `brew cleanup` was needed as I already did a `brew upgrade` and this error was the result of that with node.

Comment: @AbandonedCart I voted negative because I thought this command dangerous for beginners. It's like estimulating Linux beginners to use  rm -rf. Sorry, my opinion.

Comment: @mpoletto no worries! I try to give the appropriate warnings in the answer so anyone considering the solution would understand the impact.

Comment: @mpoletto I appreciate your concern for beginners, even if I am not sure why I was tagged.

Comment: @AbandonedCart Sorry, but it doesn't appear or I can't see where I tagged you.

Comment: This is a terrible response. Way too general. People who know what they're doing can get general solution out of specific solution, but people who don't know what they're doing can't get specific solution out of general solution like this.

Comment: @J.Ko you aren't completely wrong, but is not a good solution one that works? This error can occur due to a variety of brew issues and it seems to have helped get at least a few people unstuck. If you have a better solution I will happily upvote your answer.

Comment: @VimDiesel I don't have a solution. That's why I'm here looking for one. The one below this by Grey Black worked.

Comment: `brew upgrade` worked for me, I didn't need the cleanup

Comment: `brew cleanup` worked for me but I also had to do a `brew update-reset` to fix brew afterward, as in [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913258/1399438).

Comment: @xgMz thank you, `brew upgrade npm` works for me after cleanup

Comment: I am in the same situation as @mpoletto, and I had one version of PHP pinned. SO for my this is what worked :`brew unpin php@7.4 && brew upgrade php@7.4 && brew pin php@7.4`

Comment: It worked for me, though it's wise as advised to consider that it would end up upgrading all you brew-dependent packages. In my case the upgrade did no harm, and I was able to run my react-native project again.

Comment: @AbandonedCart, let me consider about two things: 1) you can, eventually, need to maintain old versions in production as the real life is not a ideal life where you can do the most apropriate thing you would like to do - there are some legacy systems that need to stay running until you can upgrade to a better secure version of it; 2) beside this, without a notice (the author updated the answer), there wasn't danger only for begginers - and I can't realize why you were worried about if you didn't produced the answer.

Comment: @Havingalifeonabeach Despite what you may think, I have not been holding my breath the last two years for a response. My reasoning, along with any argument you may have, is obsolete. I suggest moving on.

Comment: `brew reinstall icu4c` worked for me.

Answer (score 336):

In my case, that happened because icu4c was upgraded to version 63 but my locally installed postgres image still referenced icu4c 62.1. Therefore I had to change the icu4c version used:

```
 brew info icu4c
 brew switch icu4c <version>
```

Where `version` is the installed version returned by `info`.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me as well, and you got me on the right track. The major caveat to this approach is that you have to have previously installed this version. I worked around this in my answer

Comment: I did not have 62.1 installed.  `brew list icu4c` showed a files from `/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/63.1`.  `brew switch icu4c 63.1` fixed it for me.

Comment: I found this page after finding this error in my Postgres logs. I also tried `brew switch icu4c 63.1` but still getting the same error in the logs, even after restarting postgres. Not sure what to do next...

Comment: I ended up running `brew reinstall postgres` and that seemed to solve my problems

Comment: Helps switch to `icu4c 61.1`. `63.1` - not solve. `62.1` - not found.

Comment: Thanks @grey-black it worked for me

I am using following MacOS Mojave version 10.14.4 (18E226)

Comment: @ApoorvParijat `62.1` is only what Grey Black had installed, not part of a literal command for every user on every system.

Comment: Magic. Helped with 6.4 -> 6.3

Comment: And I ended up with `brew reinstall php@7.2`

Comment: Explicitly switching to the already installed compatible version did the trick for me.
postgres was looking for v64. v64 was indeed installed, it still cribbed with image not found error, but, started working when I explicitly set it to v64

Comment: Worked for me but I think you mean "Where version is the version number in the 'Library not loaded' message." 62 in the OP's case. 64.2 in my case.

Comment: Unfortunately brew switch no longer available.

Comment: The new `brew switch` command is `brew link`

Comment: I also had to do "brew upgrade postgresql"

Answer (score 148):

I am actually quite surprised that this solution has not been presented yet, and I feel like it is the easiest solution.

Go to GitHub, find the version of the brewfile that matches the version of `icu4c` that you need and get the raw version of the file (follow the links above and click `View File` then `Raw`).

Then just have brew reinstall from that url.

For example, version `62.1`:

```
brew reinstall https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/575eb4bbef683551e19f329f60456b13a558132f/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

For example, version `64.2`:

```
brew reinstall https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

**UPDATE:**

Later versions of Homebrew may require you to download the file first. If this is the case:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb
brew reinstall icu4c.rb
```

Comment: This is actually the best solution if, ```brew switch icu4c 62.1``` doesn't work for you in the first instance.

Comment: Worked great! To fix error `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.64.dylib` this command fixed it: `brew reinstall https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb`

Comment: This was exactly the solution i was looking for. I was having issues with a valet-php version still using an older version of icu4c whereas brew updated to a newer one.

Comment: In my case, this are better than reinstall PHP, because I have Oracle OCI, that is a pain to reinstall. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately **brew upgrade** removes older linked version and for people who still wanna use new version and keep brew up to date:

1)Use mentioned command to install older version 
2)Copy 64.2 dir from **/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/** somewhere locally
3)Run `brew upgrade` to install latest version of icu4c
4)Copy saved dir in to the **/usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/**
5)Now you can switch between versions: `brew switch icu4c 64.2`

Comment: For icu4c **66**: `brew reinstall https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/22fb699a417093cd1440857134c530f1e3794f7d/Formula/icu4c.rb`

Comment: For icu4c 67: brew reinstall https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/88b9cc789820f2f544d8d4a1053eebb044c2926c/Formula/icu4c.rb

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. It asks you to  `brew extract`

Comment: @brunouno You need to download the .rb file and do: `brew reinstall icu4c.rb`

Comment: version **67.1**: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/8e4cfd6b1bc8b1f02b67d3bc5f98c7fe5ad2fb8c/Formula/icu4c.rb

Comment: It's generally recommended to go off specific versions, but adding this as another option (using master/latest).

```wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/master/Formula/icu4c.rb; 
brew reinstall icu4c.rb```

Comment: It did not worked for me, fixed by this new wonderful php tap: https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php

Comment: Simple running `brew reinstall icu4c worked for me. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: This solution worked for me. I ran ```curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/master/Formula/icu4c.rb -o icu4c.rb; brew reinstall icu4c.rb``` and that fixed the issue.

Comment: `brew reinstall icu4c` worked for me

Answer (score 105):

Run `npm version`, if you see the same error, upgrade npm.

`brew upgrade npm`.

```
==> Upgrading 1 outdated package, with result:
npm 8.1.2 -> 10.3.0
==> Upgrading npm
==> Installing dependencies for node: icu4c
==> Installing node dependency: icu4c
```

[Credits](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18760#issuecomment-394041484)

Comment: it works for my case as I'd upgraded php to v8.2 yesterday but failed halfway, however, the icu4c had already upgraded to v.72 before that (with `brew upgrade`) while the current npm version only supports 71. So upgrading npm to newest version to match the newly upgraded icu4c version solves my issue.

Comment: Hello from 2024-Feb. This is the solution that worked in my case. I am using zsh with ohmyzsh. I suspect that a brew update failed resulting in missing required files (e.g., '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file)...). Regardless, commands were failing and `brew` COULD not upgrade other outdated packages due to resulting errors. Upgrading this 'npm' resolved the problem, and all subsequent brew upgrades worked.

Answer (score 84):

Turns out I, like @Grey Black, had to actually install v62.1 of icu4c. Nothing else worked.

However, `brew switch icu4c 62.1` only works if you have installed 62.1 in the past. If you haven't there's more legwork involved. Homebrew does [not make it easy to install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3987683/3072442) previous versions of formulae.

Here's how I did it:

1. We first need a deep clone of the Homebrew repo. This may take a while: `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) fetch --unshallow`
2. `brew log icu4c` to track down a commit that references 62.1; [`575eb4b`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/575eb4b) does the trick.
3. `cd $(brew --repo homebrew/core)`
4. `git checkout 575eb4b -- Formula/icu4c.rb`
5. `brew uninstall  --ignore-dependencies icu4c`
6. `brew install icu4c` You should now have the correct version of the dependency! Now just to...
7. `git reset && git checkout .` Cleanup your modified recipe.
8. `brew pin icu4c` Pin the dependency to prevent it from being accidentally upgraded in the future

If you decide you *do* want to upgrade it at some point, make sure to run `brew unpin icu4c`

Comment: When I do `brew log icu4c`, there's only 3-4 results. None mention 62.1. The hash you use above doesn't work either. Have they removed 62?

Comment: You should first do `git -C (brew --repo homebrew/core) fetch --unshallow` to make sure you have a full brew git history.

Comment: This is the only solution out there that worked for me, thank you! In my case the problem was ffmpeg package which, I assume, installed newer version of `icu4c`. Neither updating, upgrading brew worked, nor reinstalling, relinking, building php from source.

Comment: For me, I needed an even older version of icu4c. Applying these steps but searching for an older commit worked. To see which version you need, check the file in your error msg: `libicui18n.61.dylib` - in my case this meant I needed v.61.

Comment: Worked for me except I had to use `git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow` for step #1

Comment: In my case I've needed icu4c v63, so the related commit to checkout is [bc0c97952453ff6afc146aa3a706e9902aba4300](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/bc0c97952453ff6afc146aa3a706e9902aba4300). The git command is `git checkout bc0c97952453ff6afc146aa3a706e9902aba4300 -- Formula/icu4c.rb` and then `brew switch 63.1`

Comment: @gedijedi I recently installed ffmpeg and encountered the same error. Performing an update (`brew upgrade`) resolved the issue automatically and `brew switch` restored the php version I was using. No need to DIY a whole installation.

Comment: I believe there's an easier way to do this (install a "previous" version of something via bew) ... this SO post worked simply and flawlessly for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55828190

Comment: Remeber to do ``` brew update``` before ```brew install icu4c```. As well, fetch the unshallow the command shown does not work, so what I did was cd $(brew --repo homebrew/core) then fetch --unshallow

Comment: I don't know why but it installed the 64.1 version again instead of 62.1. 
I think ```brew update``` is required before installing it again.

Comment: this worked for me (like a charm!) thanks a lot! I was looking for version 64 (without a minor) I found (searching manually in GitHub) this commit: `896d1018c7a4906f2c3fa1386aaf283497db60a2` which references version "64.2" but it worked! php@5.6 is now working!

Comment: This resulted in `==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/icu4c/manifests/67.1
#=#=-#  #
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Failed to download resource "icu4c_bottle_manifest"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/icu4c/manifests/67.1` when I tried to get version `67.1` with https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/88b9cc789820f2f544d8d4a1053eebb044c2926c.

Comment: It did not worked for me, fixed by this new wonderful php tap: https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php

Comment: Ok so `brew` has moved on. The command structure has changed and the format of the "formula" has too. I got past the format by editing the ruby to suit the new format. It doesn't help me though becuase, as @bluepanda said, `https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/icu4c/manifests/64.2` is gone. I did find an alternative formula though, and it did work for me: https://gist.github.com/bbatsche/c1c747bb9297661772ae7e106c556c3f. I used `wget` to pull the file and then `brew reinstall Icu4c@64.rb` followed by `brew link Icu4c@64`. I'll now retire to the simplicity of my archlinux box :)

Comment: `fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense` ‍♂️ and just running `git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core)` shows git help and doesn't do anything

Answer (score 78):

For me the solution was to:

```
brew reinstall icu4c
```

Then

```
gem uninstall charlock_holmes
gem install charlock_holmes
```

Comment: Just `brew reinstall icu4c` did the job for me. Thanks.

Comment: The solution for me was `brew reinstall icu4c`

Comment: For me it only worked to reinstall `charlock_holmes`

Comment: This worked for me to fix the error with `vips`.

Answer (score 63):

I had the same problem after I upgraded my `macOS` to version `10.13.6`. I can't run `composer` and `php` commands. After researching for a while and trying various solutions posted online, reinstalling php using `homebrew` worked.

`brew reinstall php@7.1`

**Added on March 14th based on Ryan's comment**

get the version you are currently using by running `php -v` and get the right formulae (which you can find here: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/php) to replace `@7.1` in the above command.

Comment: I got the same error running `node` after upgrading macOS to `10.14.2`, `brew reinstall node` was the ticket for me too

Comment: I started getting this error after installing a new package with brew. Doing `brew upgrade` fixed it for me.

Comment: `brew reinstall php` may end up installing a different version to the current one. You may have to specify the version using `php@7.1`

Comment: you can't get the current version by running `php -v` if your php is broken :p

Comment: @gingerCodeNinja that's true, perhaps this might help: for Mac OS, go to terminal and run `echo $PATH` (if you have `php`, you should see something like this: `/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin`) this is one way to find out what versions are currently being used.

Answer (score 45):

This fixed it for me:

```
brew upgrade node
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I never fully investigated it but I believe brew just fixed the dependencies as well while upgrading node. This felt a lot more contained in comparison to brew upgrade.

Comment: seems similar case, > 'brew reinstall node' did help me after switching to Catalina

Comment: Oddly enough, this `/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.66.dylib` error suddenly occurred when I was running rspec. I stashed my handful of code changes, error still showed up. upgrading node fixed the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks :) I was about to try the other solutions - but this fixed my issue right away.

Answer (score 18):

I actually tried all of the solutions which made sense, mentioned in this post and yet i still got the same error when running `php -v` or `composer`.
The node version was fine, npm as well there were no issues on having installed correct versions and they were all running.
Running `reinstall php@7.1` just threw an error.
In the end i had to run:

```
brew reinstall icu4c
```

This basically worked, with me having to manually then install php dependencies such as `imagick.so`, `imap.so`
As these libraries were installed for a project that i no longer maintain i can go without them. But if you do have dependancies on them, have in mind that there will be more work to do afterwards.

Comment: this worked for me! `npm install` wasn't working after my work macbook force updated to Catalina last week. Found here originally: https://gist.github.com/berkedel/d1fc6d13651c16002f64653096d1fded

Answer (score 15):

Seems like it is impossible to link `icu4c` using `brew` after latest OS X update. Which makes things more interesting. The only solution I found working for me:

1. Download and compile `icu4c` 62.1 to `/usr/local/icu4c/62.1`

```
mkdir ~/sources
cd ~/sources
wget http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/62.1/icu4c-62_1-src.tgz
tar xvzf icu4c-62_1-src.tgz
cd icu/source/

sudo mkdir /usr/local/icu4c/62.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/icu4c/62.1
make
sudo make install
```

2. Link libs:

```
ln -s /usr/local/icu4c/62.1/lib/*.dylib /usr/local/include/
```

3. Set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/include
```

Comment: I'm running PHP 7.1 and this was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: In my case I needed the 64.2 version, so I downloaded it from https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-64-2/icu4c-64_2-src.tgz

Comment: After updating to OS Big Sur, icu4c 67 was missing, tried all kinds of solutions but this was the only one that worked. Downloaded it from https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-67-1/icu4c-67_1-src.tgz . Thank you!

Comment: This was moved to here: https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-62-2/icu4c-62_2-src.tgz

Comment: for `node@12` with `icu4c@71.1` works via `$ ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c@71.1/71.1/lib/*.dylib /usr/local/lib/`

Answer (score 11):

Just `brew remove php` and `brew install php` did not work, nor did `brew reinstall php`.
My solution was to do:

```
brew remove php
cd /usr/local/Cellar
rm -rf php/
brew install php
brew doctor
brew cleanup
```

Now `php -v` gives me:

```
PHP 7.3.2 (cli) (built: Feb 14 2019 10:08:45) ( NTS )
```

Answer (score 8):

my issue:

```
# npm install -g canvas

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.64.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
```

for now 20210118, after many try:

```
...
brew reinstall https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/master/Formula/icu4c.rb
brew upgrade npm
brew install node
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node@8 icu4c
brew install icu4c
...
```

Final **worked** solution is:

`brew reinstall npm`

Comment: `brew reinstall npm` command solved my problem

Answer (score 7):

For me `brew reinstall nodejs` fixed this - my issue was with running Elixir/Phoenix so not PHP specific, I think it was caused by `brew install postgres`, but reinstalling that didn't help. I was getting it from `npm` commands.

Answer (score 7):

### **2021-02**  Easy solution

After years of dealing with this problem the following, surprisingly easy, solution worked for me:

1. Open the raw file in your web browser of the version you need:

Version 62: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/575eb4bbef683551e19f329f60456b13a558132f/Formula/icu4c.rb

Version 64: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb

Version 66: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/22fb699a417093cd1440857134c530f1e3794f7d/Formula/icu4c.rb

Version 67: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/88b9cc789820f2f544d8d4a1053eebb044c2926c/Formula/icu4c.rb

Latest version: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/master/Formula/icu4c.rb

2. Copy paste the contents into a new file named:
   icu4c.rb
3. Run the following on the newly created file: `brew reinstall icu4c.rb`

Source: https://gist.github.com/hgrimelid/703691ab48c4a4d0537cfe835b4d55a6

Comment: I found a similar set of instructions, but it requires compiling the source: https://www.programmersought.com/article/34721476513/, which worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

For me it was appearing for node@12
And the following steps worked for me -

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies icu4c
brew install node
```

which installed icu4c automatically and fixed the whole thing.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I found the solution directly on homebrew page: https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues

Upgrading macOS can cause errors like the following:

- dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.54.dylib
  configure: error: Cannot find libz
- Following a macOS upgrade it may be necessary to reinstall the Xcode Command Line Tools and brew upgrade all installed formula:

```
xcode-select --install
brew upgrade
```

In my case the problem wasn't related to upgrading OS, but the solution worked nicely.

Comment: This did the trick for me after upgrading to mac OS 11.6 Big Sur. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`brew update && brew upgrade` worked for me

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your collaboration is welcome. In this case, there are 15 more questions so it will be a good point to show the Pros of yours.

Answer (score 5):

i followed this article [here](https://medium.com/@mahcloud/mac-brew-node-10-upgrade-55d3e910eebb) and this seems to be the missing piece of the puzzle for me:

```
brew uninstall node@8
```

Comment: After trying every suggestion from different forms my error stopped after using this but now we have an issue regarding npm after reinstalling node

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me.  What did work for me was a variation of this answer:  `brew remove node && brew install node`

Answer (score 4):

In order to downgrade, i had to recompile from source (MacOS Mojave)

```
$ wget https://ssl.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/62.1/icu4c-62_1-src.tgz
$ tar xvfz icu4c-62_1-src.tgz
$ cd icu/sources
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what finally worked for me.

`brew reinstall postgres`

After running the above command you might need to run

`brew postgresql-upgrade-database`

to access your previous data.

Comment: This worked for me. MacOS Montery, PostgreSQL 14.3

Answer (score 4):

Lots of answers around restoring the missing version of `icu4c`. I had this same error with `postgresql` and I imagine this can manifest with various programs that depend on dynamically linking that library.

For me, I'm using a specific version of `postgresql`, namely `postgresql@12`. I found the simplest fix was to reinstall that

```
brew reinstall postgresql@12
```

I imagine that would work for `php` as well.

Comment: This solution worked for me after running `brew reinstall postgresql@14`, `brew doctor` and `brew cleanup`.

Answer (score 3):

On MacOS Mojave, only way I could fix it was with `brew upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than install an old version of `icu4c` that the older (precompiled) php can link to, it's better to recompile the old php to link to the more recent library.

```
brew uninstall php@7.2
brew install --build-from-source php@7.2
```

This will build php and link it to the newer library. I found `reinstall` didn't quite work; the new install choked when the destination folder already existed.

I also did `brew link --force php@7.2` for my environment.

Comment: Tried this but no improvement; Grey Black's `brew switch icu4c 62.1` command worked for me, however.

Comment: note that php 7 formulae are no longer available, so once you uninstall 7.x it's gone for good

Answer (score 2):

I had problems because my version of PHP (7.3) was expecting icu4c 63 and brew would only install 64.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55828190/2000947 helped me install 63.

Comment: after searching for a while, this is what helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On OSX 10.15.4 running `xcode-select --install` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

The solution in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/berkedel/d1fc6d13651c16002f64653096d1fded) did it for me

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node icu4c
brew install node
```

Answer (score 1):

Leland's answer worked for me, but I had to change steps 4 and 6 to:

4) git checkout -B icu4c-62.1 575eb4b

6) brew reinstall Formula/icu4c.rb

Answer (score 1):

In my case, brew update icu4c to version 67.1 so my php7.1 doesn't work.
Just reinstall icu4c, then it fine.

Ref this: https://devhoi.com/threads/error-dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-64-dylib-with-php7-1.26/

Comment: i simply re-installed php 7.3 which is what was broken and it fixed it also. This guide pointed me in the right direction though.

Answer (score 1):

## [2022 Build It Yourself Edition]

Works for me on Mac OS 11.6.8 Big Sur.

```
$ wget https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-69-1/icu4c-69_1-src.tgz
$ # In Finder, copy from Downloads/ to your home directory
$ tar xzvf icu4c-69_1-src.tgz
$ cd icu/source
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

After that, `node` and `npm` worked again.

### References

- @Taher's answer
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63045892/16681513

Comment: this exact problem i am getting

Answer (score 1):

Needed to set correct version of PHP

This worked for me:

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

and then

```
brew cleanup
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me `brew reinstall php@8.3` // replace your version

Answer (score 0):

Got this error, too, after installing php 7.3. I had it resolved upgrading just my old php's versions (5.6 and 7.0, not from the official repos).

The maintainers had compiled new php versions against the current icu4c.

In my case, PHP 7 got from 0.31 to 0.33, and the problem was solved.

Comment: Isn't this covered by the other answers?

Comment: IMO, no. One answer talks about recompiling, and what I've to do is "update".

Comment: I got this error too after upgrading from an unofficial repo but brew upgrade node fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to switch between two versions of icu4c since I still maintain PHP 5.6 projects (which use the old icu4c 64.2). brew install and reinstall from raw .rb links always replaces the previously installed versions for some reason.

```
#fetching 64.2
brew fetch https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb 

#fetching stable version
brew fetch https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/master/Formula/icu4c.rb 

cd $(brew --cache)/downloads
tar xvfz e2a83648f37dc5193016ce14fa6faeb97460258b214e805b1d7ce8956e83c1a7--icu4c-64.2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
tar xvfz e045a709e2e21df31e66144a637f0c77dfc154f60183c89e6b04afa2fbda28ba--icu4c-67.1.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
mv -n icu4c/67.1 $(brew --cellar)/icu4c/
mv -n icu4c/64.2 $(brew --cellar)/icu4c/
```

then switch between versions

```
$ brew switch icu4c 64.2
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1
Opt link created for /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2

$ brew switch icu4c 67.1
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/64.2
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1
Opt link created for /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [**2020] edition**

For me, it was installing icu4c with the needed version.

If you need to install the old version like version 62, (same steps for else versions), you need to:

1. Create your own repo (or find someones repo) with this version of
   brew tap (links are different for every version):

#### version 62

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/575eb4bbef683551e19f329f60456b13a558132f/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

#### version 64

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

#### version 66

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/22fb699a417093cd1440857134c530f1e3794f7d/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

#### version 67

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/88b9cc789820f2f544d8d4a1053eebb044c2926c/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

2. [yourUsername]/homebrew-versions/Formula/
3. Place downloaded file to 'Formula' folder
4. `brew tap [yourUsername]/homebrew-versions`
5. `brew install [yourUsername]/homebrew-versions/icu4c`
6. You got it!

Where [yourUsername] is the name of your GitHub account or person who already have the needed version tap.

> Unfortunately, latest homebrew gives no longer a warning and now
> displays the error: Error: Calling Installation of XXX from a GitHub
> commit URL is disabled! Use 'brew extract XXX' to stable tap on GitHub
> instead. So the way to go now is to create a new repo on github called
> homebrew-versions to host the Formula in a Tap Then initialise it
> with: brew tap-new MYORG/homebrew-versions after git cloning the
> homebrew repo as suggested by Shine Hugh, copy paste the raw ruby file
> to your new Formula. Beware the funny naming convention! Example: File
> name is: gettext@0.20.2.rb Class name is: GettextAT0202 Example:
> https://github.com/nedap/homebrew-versions
>
> source:https://itnext.io/how-to-install-an-older-brew-package-add141e58d32

Comment: If you got an error, try to install from source:

//1. download file (for example, for 67) wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/88b9cc789820f2f544d8d4a1053eebb044c2926c/Formula/icu4c.rb

//2. Find link to archive inside file 'cat icu4c.rb'

//3. Download archive and install from source like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55024755/3126078

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to leave a detail summary on how to fix this issue at the current moment (this worked for me):

First go to the local installation of homebrew

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/
```

Homebrew > 2.5 remove the option to install formulas directly from git repos so we need to checkout an older version

```
git checkout 2.3.0
```

Install icu4c version (in my case 64.2 was compitable with php@7.1)

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/a806a621ed3722fb580a58000fb274a2f2d86a6d/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

Go back to current version of homebrew

```
git checkout -
```

Tell brew to use the old version of icu4c this way you can chose wich version to use if you have both intalled

```
brew switch icu4c 64.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved int by updating all the R packages:

```
update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE, ask = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have latest `icu4c` version and suffer like me from fragile software and just want `postgres`/whatever to work:

```
$ brew upgrade icu4c                                                                                                                           
Warning: icu4c 69.1 already installed
```

Then you can just make symlinks:

```
> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.68.dylib

cd /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib
ln -s libicuuc.69.1.dylib libicuuc.68.dylib
ln -s libicuio.69.1.dylib libicui18n.68.dylib
```

These symlinks will disappear the first time you update `icu4c`, but this is probably the fastest way to fix.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers were applicable to my fix which was running a dev server with node in a repo where it formerly worked.

I saw a few people mentioning reinstalling node or deinstalling certain versions but I'd like to point out that you can try switching versions of node using `nvm install/use <version>`. My system node had switched somehow and switching back to version 8 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in different ways but the only one currently worked for me was to edit the local brew icu4c formula and rebuild it.

I got the idea by opening the JSON in the formula description.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/8738720eadff2f4e16b49ac05067b1498d4b078e/Formula/icu4c.rb

I saw that there is a direct link to the github icu4c release.

I changed it with the needed version and then when I tried to build it I get an error related to the sha256 number.

The correct one is suggested directly in the console. copy paste the correct one in the local formula and try to build again.

In my case asked me to update Xcode and to download a needed package, I simply followed what it was asking for and then as last step I had to run this command

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

to accept the licence.

**Here the steps:**

```
brew edit icu4c
```

change these lines

```
url "https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-72-1/icu4c-72_1-src.tgz"
version "72.1"
sha256 "a2d2d38217092a7ed56635e34467f92f976b370e20182ad325edea6681a71d68"
```

with the needed version:

```
url "https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-71-1/icu4c-71_1-src.tgz"
version "71.1"
sha256 "67a7e6e51f61faf1306b6935333e13b2c48abd8da6d2f46ce6adca24b1e21ebf"
```

save and then

```
brew reinstall --build-from-source /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

For me that was an issue after installing phpunit into my Mac.

I had two versions of PHP installed: 7.x(default) and 8.x.

There was a clash between PHPUnit and 7.x version, which I was not really needed. All i had to do was to see what are the versions installed on my laptop via brew

```
brew list
```

Uninstall the php versions I was

```
brew uninstall php@7.4
```

and clean up the directory with php installation:

```
 rm -r /opt/homebrew/etc/php/7.4
```

After all of these I have opened a new terminal session, and all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error poped up when I attempted to init docusaurus.
Here is a simple solution that works for me:

```
nvm use --lts
```

`nvm` is required for this. No need to reinstall anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-69-1/icu4c-69_1-src.tgz
tar xvfz icu4c-69_1-src.tgz
cd icu/source
./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, next steps do the things :

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies php
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies php@7.4
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies php@8.1
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/php
```

After that, `php -v`  finally has worked

Answer (score -1):

I've tried many of the suggestions here, and at the end `brew upgrade php` is what did the trick for me, but seems the issue is all over the place

Answer (score -3):

in my case, I reinstall all packages installed with Homebrew

```
$ brew list | xargs brew reinstall
```

After that, I start to install my version that I need