# Ruby cannot load such file - active_support/core_ext/object/blank

Tags: ruby, rubygems, homebrew

I was trying to run `brew doctor` but system popped up error of

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file --
>   active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)

Searched online and another post suggested to just "gem install activesupport" but then I ran into error of:

```
ERROR:  Error installing activesupport:
    i18n requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
```

I also tried to rvm install ruby-2.3.0 but the same error popped again

```
[2019-02-26 10:07:41] requirements_osx_brew_libs_install
requirements_osx_brew_libs_install ()  { 
    brew install "$@" --force || { 
        \typeset ret=$?;
        requirements_osx_brew_libs_error "installation";
        return $ret
    } } current path: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
PATH=/Users/{user_name}/.aw/pex_resources/scripts/binaries:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/fengjiao/.rbenv/shims:/Users/{user_name}/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin:/Users/fengjiao/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/{user_name}/.rbenv/shims:/Users/{user_name}/.nvm/v0.10.32/bin:/Users/{user_name}/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/fengjiao/gocode/bin:/Users/{user_name}/.rvm/bin
command(10): requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake
libtool pkg-config coreutils libyaml readline libksba openssl@1.1
++ brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config coreutils libyaml readline libksba openssl@1.1 --force
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require': cannot load such file --
active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)    from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
`require'   from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:10:in
`<top (required)>'  from
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:21:in `<main>'
++ typeset ret=1
++ requirements_osx_brew_libs_error installation
++ rvm_warn 'There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.
```

Answer (score 242, accepted):

Running `brew style` fixed this issue for me.

---

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments, for some people the solution is:

```sh
brew update-reset
```

Comment: @Mave for me happened after I ran `brew cleanup`

Comment: @crisscross please add your command as an answer, it is only thing which worked for me, thank you :)

Comment: @BigHeadCreations , @Mave: I was able to confirm that this happened directly after a `brew cleanup`.  Just prior to this, `brew update` said gave updated commit: `6db1c7383`.  `brew update-reset` fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks!! I solved my issue using `brew update-reset`

Comment: Works for macOS 10.15

Comment: I encountered this after running `brew cleanup` after upgrade to macOS 10.15.2. The answer above fixed it.

Comment: What does `brew style` do?

Comment: @BruceSun well the [manpage](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage) says `style` is used to "check formulae or files for conformance to Homebrew style guidelines." Not sure why it helps in this situation though.

Answer (score 51):

Had the same problem. I had to run `brew update-reset` to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I face the 'sunspot_rails-2.1.0' issue while upgrade the ruby version ruby 2.2 to ruby 2.5 for rails 4.2 and here I would like to share with you which has worked for me.

"LoadError: no such file to load -- **active_support/core_ext/object/to_json**"

**Refrence**: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/555/files

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to force homebrew/linuxbrew to use its own portable-ruby to fix it.

I am running ArchLinux with ruby 2.7.0 installed, after I switch to homebrew's portable-ruby by `export HOMEBREW_FORCE_VENDOR_RUBY=1` as described in the [manpage](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Manpage.md) and issue `brew update`, homebrew automatically downloads portable-ruby 2.6.3, and everything's back to normal.

I think the root cause might be homebrew's incompatible with a higher version of ruby.