# NPM, Node fail to open after upgrade to Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently upgraded OSX from 10.13.XXX to 10.14.6. After the upgrade, NPM and Node both fail with an error message I haven't been able to find any information on.

Here's the error message that appears when running `node` or `npm` on the command line:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZTVN6icu_6213FieldPositionE
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Expected in: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/node
Abort trap: 6
```

It seems like the quickest/easiest way to fix this would be to uninstall/re-install node and npm, but I'd rather fix the actual issue if possible.

More info:

`brew reinstall node` throws this:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Installing the correct version of node is literally the fix, though. OSX does not follow semver, and its 10.14 is very much backward-compatibility-breaking. 10.14 moves OSX to "we really want to be 64 bit only", so _any_ 32 bit program you had installed on 10.13 is entirely likely in trouble: you'll have to reinstall Node. Rather than using `brew reinstall`, which can try to do some things in place, properly remove Node first, then let brew discover the OSX 64 bit version.

Comment: Hi Mike, I was able to fix using `brew reinstall` (see comment below) but I am curious how to properly remove node to use the OSX 64-bit version. Any pointers?

Comment: You'd start with `brew remove node` and then it typically reports on everything it can't remove itself, so you can manually `sudo rm` and `sudo unlink` those things.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I have a fix but I'm still not sure what caused the problem.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888582/ruby-cannot-load-such-file-active-support-core-ext-object-blank?rq=1) I found a similar issue with `brew` commands. I ran `brew style` and then `brew update-reset` and homebrew started working again. Then, `brew reinstall node` got everything working once more.