# Issues with zsh after upgrading OSX to Catalina

Tags: homebrew, macos-catalina

After upgrading my mac to Catalina, i have changed my shell from bash to zsh and when i try to run brew doctor or brew cleanup i receive a load error:

cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)

Im having other anomalies as well due to the change of shell. I have updated my .zprofile to reflect what was in my .bash_profile when i was using bash.

Any way i can get brew up and running again properly and what steps can i take to make sure zsh runs just like bash?

```
brew doctor

dc@PandaMacPro ~ % brew cleanup
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
    3: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
    2: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_support/core_ext/object/blank (LoadError)
```

Comment: also with nmap i receive an error zsh: bad CPU type in executable: nmap

Comment: When i run 'uname -a' the output shows                                                            
Darwin PandaMacPro.local 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: That's a ruby error; has nothing to do with your shell.

Comment: I've misdiagnosed the issue and you are right. It is a ruby issue.I found the fix to this problem from running brew style

Answer (score 10):

Does the command `brew update-reset`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54913258/9225961), solve your problem? It did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `brew link --overwrite nmap` it should fix the

`zsh: bad CPU type in executable: nmap`