# Install icu4c version 63 with Homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, icu4c

I was trying to start `psql` but got

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I used `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`, got the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/postgres
  Reason: image not found
[1]    2559 abort      postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

A quick search on `libicui18n.63.dylib` showed me I need `icu4c` lib with version 63. However `brew list icu4c` says I have the version 64.2.

I tried both `brew install icu4c 63` & `brew install icu4c@63` but no luck.

Can anyone help, please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Solution:

1. `cd` to Homebrew's formula directory

- Intel

  ```
  cd $(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
  ```
- M1

  ```
  cd $(brew --prefix)/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
  ```

2. Find desired commit (version 63 for `icu4c`) to checkout

```
git log --follow icu4c.rb
```

3. Checkout to a new branch

```
git checkout -b icu4c-63 e7f0f10dc63b1dc1061d475f1a61d01b70ef2cb7
```

4. Reinstall the library with the new version

```
brew reinstall ./icu4c.rb
```

5. Switch to the reinstalled version

```
brew switch icu4c 63.1
```

6. Checkout back to master

```
git checkout master
```

Sources:

- [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)
- http://hanxue-it.blogspot.com/2018/08/macos-homebrew-installing-older-version-of-software.html

Bonus for those who ended up using this more than once:

```
# zsh
function hiicu63() {
  local last_dir=$(pwd)

  cd $(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
  git checkout icu4c-63
  brew reinstall ./icu4c.rb
  brew switch icu4c 63.1
  git checkout master

  cd $last_dir
}
```

Comment: By the way, if anyone know a better/easier way to do this & share, I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Abslutely fantastic way to install an older version in brew, much easier than other methods I've seen, thanks a lot!

Comment: this worked! but it sounded like it had the potential to brick my machine! My case was: installed phpbrew php7.3, then npm and node didn't work

Comment: It's quite safe. In worst case senario, you would have to reinstall php/node. :)

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Looks like version 63 and before have been removed from the log.

Comment: @lacy I don't think anyone would force push in homebrew-core but checked just to be sure and can confirm it is still there.

Comment: If by any reason you can't see the version that you need in the git log, you can try to download the full-history before, `git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow`

Comment: This has helped me to upgrade Postgres from 13.4 to 14.6 on my MacOS, thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Like @dingusjh says, but use `reinstall` command instead of `install` in case brew complains about having icu4c installed already and you should try to `extract`. The complete command would then be:

```
brew reinstall https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/e7f0f10dc63b1dc1061d475f1a61d01b70ef2cb7/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be easier.

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/e7f0f10dc63b1dc1061d475f1a61d01b70ef2cb7/Formula/icu4c.rb
```

Comment: I've used this method with other formulae in the past, but it didn't work in this case. Gave me a recommendation to use `brew extract` instead, and the warning "icu4c 63.1 is already installed and up-to-date \n To reinstall 63.1, run `brew reinstall icu4c`"… running the reinstall command reinstalled the latest (64.2 as of this writing). Don't know if that's a new brew behavior or bug or what. Went back to getting it from the local brew tap as in ogirginc's answer

Answer (score 2):

For me reinstalling icu4c worked `brew reinstall icu4c`

Comment: Honestly this is what people should try first! good answer