# nodejs not working after installation of docker on mac

Tags: node.js, sql-server, laravel, docker

OS - mac mojave

I was installing the SQL Server on mac for laravel, so for that I found this article on internet and this says you need to install docker first, article is https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/mac/install_docker_for_sql_server_on_a_mac.cfm and after that I followed  https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/mac/install_sql-cli_on_a_mac.cfm when I run "npm install -g sql-cli" this return

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

And when I did "node-v" then I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

but before installing docker node was working, what is the issue?

Comment: Node 10's pretty old, maybe the Docker installer downgraded you? Have you tried `brew upgrade node` to fix it?

Comment: I think it is just a problem with that library, try to fix it with `brew`, o install it again.
Check this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54180353/262090