# font-awesome gem in different layout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have been happily using the `font-awesome-rails` gem for while with no issues. However I have created a new layout `admin` and when I add `@import "font-awesome";` to `admin.scss` I get the following error:

```
ExecJS::RuntimeError - dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
```

I defined my `admin.html.erb` in `layouts` with

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'admin', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

I am using better-errors gem and issue points to `image_tag` and `favicon_link_tag`. Issue is gone as soon as I remove the font-awesome from `admin.scss` and restart server.

I really want to be able to use font-awesome in diff layouts using the above gem.

Any ideas how I can overcome this?

Using rails 5.2 on MacOS High Sierra.

Update:

application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "home/animate";
@import "home/material-design-iconic-font.min";
@import "home/style";
@import "home/colors/default";
@import "font-awesome";
@import 'cookies_eu';
```

admin.scss

```
@import "font-awesome";
$mynewcolor:#642586;
```

Comment: show the scss that works and your admin.scss with the error, maybe something is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it with this SO answer: [dyld: Library not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828891/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-62-dylib-error-run). It is weird that it did not manifest before.