# PHP incompatible library version after reinstall

Tags: php, installation, version

After reinstalling PHP7.1 on Macosx I have a the following errors: Incompatible library version.

I have done this command:

> brew reinstall php@7.1

And I have this error when trying php -v

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/c-ares/lib/libcares.2.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/php
Reason: Incompatible library version: php requires version 6.0.0 or later, but 
libcares.2.dylib provides version 5.0.0
Abort trap: 6
```

I don't have any idea how to solve this and did not find anybody having the same problem

Would you have any idea how to have php working again ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib error running php after installing node with brew on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828891/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-62-dylib-error-run)

Answer (score 1):

I hit a similar error after updating Ruby on High Sierra. I was able to solve by running `brew upgrade`.