# Incompatible library version: php requires version 6.0.0 or later, but libcares.2.dylib provides version 2.0.0

Tags: php, composer-php, homebrew

I am trying to install Craft CMS using composer (composer create-project craftcms/craft) but I am getting an error that says:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/c-ares/lib/libcares.2.dylib
> Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin/php Reason: Incompatible
> library version: php requires version 6.0.0 or later, but
> libcares.2.dylib provides version 2.0.0 Abort trap: 6

I am using AMPPS if that helps, and I use PHP version 7.1, although it's saying it's providing version 2. I am also on macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

I believe this started happening after I downloaded httrack using brew. I have tried uninstalling httrack using brew but no luck.

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64431279/8878157 - did you tried it?

Answer (score -1):

Give `brew upgrade c-ares` a try.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me with an idea. I gave that a go and it did a few updates and finished by saying 'Warning: c-ares 1.17.1 already installed'. Still getting the same error when installing craft CMS using composer.

Comment: What about just a straight up "brew upgrade"?