# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using node 8. When I did npm install I received the error message
`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib   Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node`

I thought of reinstalling node. So I uninstalled node. I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x#) to uninstall node. After uninstall, I restarted my Mac and I did node -v. Even after uninstall for `node -v` I get

`dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib   Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/node`

Please help to uninstall the node completely and to get rid of the above error!

Thanks!

Comment: you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828891/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-62-dylib-error-run) ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to [dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib error running php after installing node with brew on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828891/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-62-dylib-error-run)

TLDR;
You could do

```
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
```