# NPM completely broken and won't reinstall after failed upgrade

Tags: npm, npm-install

Mac Catalina 10.15.6

I already had npm installed. I wanted to upgrade so I ran the following.

```
   npm install -g npm
```

Below is the output:

> $name@$names-MacBook-Pro desktop % npm install -g npm
> /usr/local/bin/npx -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
> /usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
> npm ERR! code EEXIST npm ERR! syscall symlink npm ERR! path
> ../../../lib/node_modules/npm/man/man1/npm-bin.1 npm ERR! dest
> /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm-bin.1 npm ERR! errno -17 npm ERR!
> EEXIST: file already exists, symlink
> '../../../lib/node_modules/npm/man/man1/npm-bin.1' ->
> '/usr/local/share/man/man1/npm-bin.1' npm ERR! File exists:
> /usr/local/share/man/man1/npm-bin.1 npm ERR! Remove the existing file
> and try again, or run npm npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files
> recklessly.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/$name/.npm/_logs/2020-10-04T14_41_02_611Z-debug.log

Now all NPM commands fail.

```
zsh: command not found: npm
```

Everything from:

```
npm -v

sudo npm install npm -g
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used home brew to upgrade NPM and it deleted and reinstalled all the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

This generally works for me on Mac:

```
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
brew install npm
```

(note you'll need the xcode tools if you don't have it - try `xcode-select --install` or check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/how-to-install-xcode-command-line-tools).)

Now, try `npm install` again and see if that changes anything.

Also, see this [potentially related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828891/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-62-dylib-error-run).