# Is it sensible to install `Node.js` through Homebrew rather than directly on macOS?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew

I learned over the years that there are some packages I should not install via Homebrew or MacPorts:

- For [complicated reasons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50502/9549) TeX/LaTeX should be installed [directly](https://www.tug.org/mactex/), not through HB/MP.
- Through experiments, it seems that [Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos.html) should likewise be installed directly.

For Python I'm on the fence. I prefer installing it separately. But like Qt, brew packages that depend on it will anyway install Python or Qt. Then it's a matter of making sure one's `PATH` is set correctly.

I still have too little experience with `Node.js`, `npm`, and `webpack`. Can you share your experiences? What's easier to maintain, `Node.js` &co installed through Homebrew or [directly](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)?

*Related:* [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53828891/).

Comment: I like `brew install npm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Node.js` under `Homebrew` is giving you trouble after a macOS upgrade

```
~/ > node 
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.67.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Reason: image not found
  Abort trap: 6
```

Then [run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54180353/)

```
~/ > brew info icu4c
icu4c: stable 67.1 (bottled) [keg-only]
...
```

followed by

```
~/ > brew switch icu4c 67.1
Warning: Calling `brew switch` is deprecated! Use `brew link` @-versioned formulae instead.
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1
Opt link created for /usr/local/Cellar/icu4c/67.1
```

and `node` will run again.

```
~/ > node
Welcome to Node.js v15.3.0.
```

Comment: $ brew switch icu4c 68.2
Error: Unknown command: switch

Comment: I just did 'brew upgrade' which downloaded the latest node.