# php version is not identified

Tags: php, terminal, php-7.4, php-8.1

As the title, php version is not identified.
Despite googling, it didn't work out.
If you suggest a solution for this problem, I appreciate it.

```
$ php -v
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuio.72.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Please provide more info. This looks like a PHP upgrade failure. See what people have to say about `libicuio php` there are a couple of topics here on this and also GitHub issues.

Comment: Yes, agree, you should try to add more helpful info.  Was it an upgrade failure?  I found this which may help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828891/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-62-dylib-error-run

Comment: You tagged it php-7.4 and php-8.1 so I guess you were upgrading.