# Error while running a JS file in node in VScode in MacBook air m1

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, macos, homebrew

Recently we had a hackathon where we had to work with PostgreSQL, so after I installed it in my Macbook using Homebrew, I tried running a JS file in the terminal (had already installed NodeJS), but it showed this error.

```
> dyld[33088]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib
  Referenced from: <FA9BB294-03DF-3FB7-A7BF-EC2FCC767823> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/21.6.2/bin/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort
```

node "/Users/omswaroopnayak/Desktop/vscode/webd/server.js"

I typed `omswaroopnayak@Oms-MacBook-Air webd % node "/Users/omswaroopnayak/Desk top/vscode/webd/server.js"` (using code runner in VScode)

Where I expected the the server to run and output the same in terminal, but instead I got this.

```
> dyld[33088]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib
  Referenced from: <FA9BB294-03DF-3FB7-A7BF-EC2FCC767823> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/21.6.2/bin/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file)
zsh: abort
      node "/Users/omswaroopnayak/Desktop/vscode/webd/server.js"
was shown
```

Comment: Try cleaning up homebrew.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53828891/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-opt-icu4c-lib-libicui18n-62-dylib-error-run

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago I started to get the same error in VS Code when it would attempt to run `npm run lint` during a pre-commit hook. The only thing I'd changed around that time was that I'd installed the `oci-cli` homebrew formula, which is a python-based CLI tool, and uninstalling that did not fix the issue, so I'm not 100% sure if that was the cause.

The issue was resolved after upgrading all my homebrew packages:

```bash
brew upgrade
```

If upgrading all of your homebrew packages is not something you want to do right now, I'd recommend you first try upgrading `node` only. Mine was upgraded from `21.6.2 -> 21.7.1`:

```bash
brew upgrade node
```

In case that doesn't address the issue, here is the complete list of packages that were upgraded on my system:

```
go 1.22.0 -> 1.22.1
gh 2.44.1 -> 2.45.0
libpng 1.6.42 -> 1.6.43
vercel-cli 33.5.1 -> 33.5.5
libunistring 1.1 -> 1.2
glib 2.78.4 -> 2.80.0
c-ares 1.26.0 -> 1.27.0
xz 5.6.0 -> 5.6.1
libnghttp2 1.59.0 -> 1.60.0
sqlcmd 1.5.0 -> 1.6.0
libpq 16.2 -> 16.2_1
python-typing-extensions 4.9.0 -> 4.10.0
pcre2 10.42 -> 10.43
node 21.6.2 -> 21.7.1
git 2.43.2 -> 2.44.0
```

Check if you have any of those packages installed and if so, try upgrading them. You can see a list of packages/versions you have installed with:

```bash
brew list --versions | sort
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Had the same issue after I noticed a local Postgres v16 installed as brew service wasn't coming up. Upgrading brew package resolved this