# Error in installing PostgreSQL in macOS using HomeBrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I was experimenting on macOS and tried

1. installing postgresql@11 using HomeBrew. Everything went well at first.
2. After that, I uninstalled it
3. this time installed postgresql@14 which went fine too.
4. I uninstalled postgresql@14
5. I wanted to install postgresql@11 again

but this time I am having problems.

```
*dyld[78742]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib
  Referenced from: <0F8BEC0C-41F5-3781-B77A-20C013908EA6> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.22_1/bin/postgres
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file),
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file),
'/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), 
'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), 
'/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file),
'/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), 
'/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
no data was returned by command ""/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.22_1/bin/postgres" -V"
The program "postgres" is needed by initdb but was not found in the same directory as "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.22_1/bin/initdb".
Check your installation.
```

I can start postgresql@11 as a service but when I run psql, I get this:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I tried `brew link --overwrite postgresql@11` but I still get the same problems.

Comment: Probably that is becasue default port 5432 is in use by version 14? 
Maybe this helps. On Mac, my preference is to use Postgres.app from https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html. Although current versions do not have 11, I believe you can find it too in older downloads. Or another option I often use is Docker containers for postgress, in fact I have multiple versions of postgreSQL running in Docker containers both in Mac and Windows.

Comment: Thank you for this. I found PostgreSQL 11 under legacy downloads in the link you provided. This is another option.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well after I restarted my computer after updating a bunch of applications. By checking the `/usr/local/var/log/postgresql@11.log`, I could see that `postgresql@11` was looking for version 73 of `icu4c`. In your error message, you can see lines like `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib` which is looking for a version 73 file under the 74.2 folder. To see which version of `icu4c` you currently have, run:

```
brew info icu4c
```

Upgrading to `postgresql@14` may have updated your version to 74. The solution presented in this [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56242725/23848808) was able to resolve my issue. Specifically for the latest 73:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/9ca237a7bc85e854c8465c9ad08f8a333ba27a44/Formula/i/icu4c.rb
brew install icu4c
```

followed by restarting `postgresql@11`

```
brew services restart postgresql@11
```

To get a different version of `icu4c`, search through the history [homebrew-core repo](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/i/icu4c.rb) for the version you need and then select the **Raw** button to grab the URL.

Additionally, if you get *Library not loaded* errors when running wget for the first time, try reinstalling it:

```
brew reinstall wget
```