# PG ConnectionBad Could not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

Full error is:

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):


pg (1.2.3) lib/pg.rb:58:in `initialize'
pg (1.2.3) lib/pg.rb:58:in `new'
pg (1.2.3) lib/pg.rb:58:in `connect'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:46:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:889:in `new_connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:933:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:912:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:873:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:595:in `checkout'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:439:in `connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:1121:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:238:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:206:in `connection'
activerecord (6.0.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:562:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (3.12.4) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.4) lib/puma/server.rb:675:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.4) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.4) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.4) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I tried rm the postmaster.pid but then it prints no such file. I also tried restarting postgresql multiple times but it keeps printing the same exact error. 
I know that there is not much thats all the info I have regarding the problem

Comment: What platform? Versions? Have you rebooted the entire system? Can you you run `psql` and connect? Please read the guidelines on how to ask questions.

Comment: I had a similar issue, just posted my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64020320/5725619).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will send you some steps that help me with this issue:

1. **CHECKING POSTGRES STATUS AND RUNNING PORT (if it is on 5432):**

**Ubuntu/Linux Distros (Terminal):**

```
$ pg_lsclusters
```

or

```
$ systemctl status postgresql.service
```

or

```
$ service postgresql status
```

**Windows:**

*Ctrl+R* type *services.msc*

You should find the postgres status and the port which it is running

2. **STARTING POSTGRES SERVICE:**

**Ubuntu/Linux Distros (Terminal):**

```
$ systemctl start postgresql.service
```

or

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
```

**Windows**

*Ctrl + R* type *services.msc* find your postgres service and just start it.

3. **CHECKING AND CREATING USER ROLE ON POSTGRES**

   First connect to the database:

   `$ sudo su postgres`

   `$ psql`

Then check if your role is created with the command:

```
$ \du
```

If it's not created yet you can create by using:

```
$ CREATE role name_of_your_role_here WITH createdb login password 'your_password_here';
```

After that you could try again to connect to the database:

don't forget to use

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

and configure *database.yml* file on your application

4. **Change Client Authentication Method on PG_HBA.CONF**

You can see more details of it right here: [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

You would probably use md5 password method or no auth at all for tests purpose

To do that, you could change the METHOD column of your localhost from peer(default) to md5

You can find this file on:

**LINUX DISTROS:**

> cd /etc/postgresql/***your postgres version here***/main/pg_hba.conf

**WINDOWS:**

> C:/Porgram Files/PostgresSQL/***your postgres version
>   her***/data/pg_hba.conf

**Option method with simple user/password:**

```
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

IPv4 local connections:

host  all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5 <= CHANGE HERE
```

**Option method with no Password:**

```
TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

IPv4 local connections:

host  all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust <= CHANGE HERE
```

Comment: `sudo service postgresql start` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Windows 10**

In my case, PostgreSQL Server wasn't running so I had to start it as follows:

1. Open the **Run** app
2. Type `services.msc`
3. Find **postgresql-x64-13 - PostgreSQL Server 13** (Its description is: Provides relational database storage.)
4. Right click, and select **Start**