# MacOS: have somehow ended up with two versions of postgres, which should I use?

Tags: postgresql, osx-lion, postgresql-9.1

I've installed postgres from MacPorts, on MacOS Lion. I'm now rather confused about what to do next, as I can't find one clear set of documentation about setup.

I have ended up with two versions of postgres on my machine, one at `/usr/bin/psql` and one at `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql`. Does MacOS ship with a version of postgres?

Anyway, given that I have ended up with two versions:

1. Which of these should I add to my path?
2. Should I delete the other one?
3. Some sets of documentation say I should make sure some of the postgres directories are owned by the `postgres` user. Is this correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Argh, yes, it looks like Lion comes with a version of postgres: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion - now wondering if I should delete the other one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want.  If you are trying to distribute software that will run on Lion, use the version that comes with your operating system.  If you want to use a more recent version with additional major features, use the more recent version.

In general I recommend sticking with commonly distributed versions when you want to distribute your own software.