# Postgres permission denied on MAC OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, postgresql, osx-lion

I was following the ruby on rails tutorial to run with postgres but when I try the "rake db:create" I get the following error:

```
could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have found this question issuing some similar problem but I couldnt make it work anyway.

[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

I have installed homebrew after reading this question and the path is fine, brew doctor shows me no errors on path.

Comment: _Is_ PostgreSQL listening on `/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432`? What does `ls -l /var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432` show? What does `fuser /var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432` show?

Comment: Fisrt shows: ls: /var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432: Permission denied
Second shows: /usr/bin/fuser: '/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432' does not exist

Comment: That `ls` output is funny; re-run the command with `sudo`...

Comment: Also `ls -ld /var/pgsql_socket` . Sounds like the socket dir perms may be odd.

Comment: running with sudo: `ls: /var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Instead of troubleshooting your **socket file** permissions, you could try a **TCP connection**. Add `host: localhost` to your `config/database.yml`. Of course, this will only work if postgres is listening for TCP traffic. Postgres listens on port 5432 by default, so `netstat -an | grep 5432` will tell you if it is listening.

**References**

- [PostgreSQL Documentation: 18.3. Connections and Authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html).

Comment: If `netstat -an | grep 5432` produces no output, then postgres is not listening on the normal port, or is not listening on any port.

Comment: Check the server settings related to connections.  Read chapter 18.3. "Connections and Authentication" http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: adding host: localhost fixed the problem for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, may be you are open postgre in another application, like **pgadmin** http://www.pgadmin.org/
Try to close any application that use postgre SQL and run your command again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today and found this blog post below which helped me:

http://nextmarvel.net/blog/2011/09/brew-install-postgresql-on-os-x-lion/

> It moves your OS X default postgres binaries into an archive folder and symlinks the homebrew versions in place of them.

**TL;DR**
`curl http://nextmarvel.net/blog/downloads/fixBrewLionPostgres.sh | sh`

Comment: This did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After unsuccessfully trying all the suggestions posted above, I finally quit out of terminal and restarted it.

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your config/database.yml has------host: localhost and port: (check for yourself by netstat -an | grep 5432 or 5433)

Answer (score -2):

I also ran into this problem because I had both the mysql and pg gems active in my Gemfile.

I commented out the mysql gem:

```
# mysql
```

Then ran:

```
bundle install
```

and then:

```
rake db:migrate
```

and it worked like a charm.