# Passenger (under Apache, running a Rails app) is not connecting to Postgres, but gives useless error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, apache, passenger

I have a pair of apps I'd like to run on one server, under `CentOS 7`,`Apache 2.4`,`Passenger 5.2.3`,`Rails 5.1.3`, and `Ruby 2.3.1`. One app uses `PostgreSQL (9.6.5)` (the other uses `MySQL`). When started, one app shows the following error:

```
[ D 2018-04-30 18:18:09.6842 29585/Tq age/Cor/Spa/Spawner.h:713 ]: [App 29639 stdout] !> Error
[ D 2018-04-30 18:18:09.6842 29585/Tq age/Cor/Spa/Spawner.h:713 ]: [App 29639 stdout] !> 
[ E 2018-04-30 18:18:09.7171 29585/Tq age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:305 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/html/my_carrier_packets: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: c1c03884
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-ffVmuJ.html
  Message from application: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
 (PG::ConnectionBad)
  /var/www/html/my_carrier_packets/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:56:in `initialize'
...
```

The "**Error details**" file is functionally a restatement of what's above, with slightly more data, the `.s.PGSQL.5432` does, and there's nothing I can find searching the Error ID listed.

What am I missing? What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was (eventually) [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10791904/postgres-permission-denied-on-mac-os-x/10793186#10793186). Which was referenced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14225289/1888553).

So, to recap: if you're running Rails under Apache (and possibly other web servers), your database configuration can be the source of what look like connection errors.