# Postgres just randomly stopped working (Rails, PGSQL.5432)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've been using the same Postgres database in this same app for a month with no problems, and I didn't change anything in the database before this error randomly came up today. However, today Postgres randomly started throwing this error when I try to "rails s" (I get the same type of error when running createdb or createuser):

Exiting
/Users/Joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::Error)
       Is the server running locally and accepting
       connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

What's really weird is that my friend had the exact same errors yesterday (working on the same app), and it was fixed by him running the script from http://nextmarvel.net/blog/2011/09/brew-install-postgresql-on-os-x-lion/.  After running the script, he uninstalled and reinstalled the PG gem to make everything work.  However, he is running OS X Lion, and I am running Snow Leopard, so that script wouldn't work for me.

Any ideas of (1) why this would randomly start happening and (2) how to fix it?

Comment: Is PostgreSQL running? Did you reboot and forget to start it?

Comment: Yes it's running.  We verified by running the 'lunchy start postgres' command, and the output said that PosgresSQL was running.

Comment: Can you connect to it with `psql`?

Comment: Yes the console was showing our test psql commands worked fine.

Comment: Does `/tmp/s.PGSQL.5432` exist? What are its permissions?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem today, although in my case postgres (installed via homebrew on MacOS 10.8) wasn't running but I couldn't start or restart it. It appeared that due to a crash a zombie was blocking the socket, to resolve it i did the following

```
lsof -i :5432
```

this showed the PID of the process blocking, I simply killed it with

```
kill -9 PID
```

and postgres restarted fine.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

- Maybe something deleted `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` socket - a `/tmp/` cleaning service for example.
- Maybe you'll be able to connect using `:host => 'localhost'` as connection argument for `PG::Connection.new()` — it will avoid problems with locating proper path for Unix socket or file permissions problems.
- If you do not want to use `localhost` (it probably is a little slower than a socket) then you can find where it is using `lsof | grep PGSQL` command as operating system administrator — if it is for example `/var/run/postgres/.s.PGSQL.5432` — you would use `:host => '/var/run/postres/'`.

Comment: Tom, I know this is old answer but I am having the exact same problem, can you tell me how to stop the link /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 from stop getting deleted after system reboot ? as right now I have to manually create the link through "sudo ln -s /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"

Comment: iCyborg: You cannot prevent /tmp/ from cleaning as probably it is a tmpfs (a directory in memory). You can add `ln -s ...` to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` startup script.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and when I checked server.log I can see it was not able to find that var/postgres folder and some of the conf files.

I did this, however I lost my data in that case

```
brew uninstall postgres
brew install postgres
initdb `brew --prefix`/var/postgres/data -E utf8``
```

That worked well for me and everything back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when starting rails (No such file or directory). **Re-installing postgres with the [PostgreSQL one-click installer](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) and rebooting** resolved the issue.

In my case this happened after installing Mountain Lion, which probably cleaned the tmp directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and found this answer helpfull

[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

I resolved by adding

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to my .bash_profile