# Issue with Postgresql `initialize` ... Socket .s.PGSQL.5432

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql

There have been a few post on this issue, unfortunately none of the solutions have worked for me.

My suspicion is that my postgresql is either not running or not configured correctly.

Here is where I am at, I have a development project I have joined, they are using postgresql. Here are the step I have take to get here:

- Cloned Repo
- Changed name of config/ database.yml.sample -> database.yml
- Changed name of config/ s3.yml.sample -> s3.yml
- Ran bundle install
- Ran Rake db:migrate

resulting in this error:

> rake aborted!
>   could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Here is what my files currently look like:
Database.yml

> development:
>      adapter: postgresql
>      encoding: unicode
>      database: rentsnapper_development
>      pool: 5
>      username: user
>      password:
>
> test: &test
>       adapter: postgresql
>       encoding: unicode
>       database: rentsnapper_test
>       pool: 5
>       username: user
>       password:
>    cucumber:
>       <<: *test

And My s3.yml

> defaults: &defaults
>      access_key_id:
>      secret_access_key:
>   development:
>       <<: *defaults
>       photos_bucket: rentsnapper-photos-development

Solutions Tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887090/2066855
  No File listed
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14225289/2066855
  No Change, when I run rake db:migrate I get the same error
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15788389/2066855
  Nothing happened

Also as a side question that may or may not be relevant linux is telling me that "ruby-1.9.3-p385 is not installed", I'm running ruby-1.9.3-p362, I suspect this is unrelated. Is this something I need to update or can I get by with my current version.

Thank you in advanced...

Comment: OK just got some advice, Looks like I am missing postgresql, I am downloading it now from http://postgresapp.com/

Comment: At this point I definitely have postgresql running and I am getting the same error, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED: I had to fix my database.yml file. Added "host: localhost" took out user & password lines.

> development:
>        adapter: postgresql
>        encoding: unicode
>        database: rentsnapper_development
>        pool: 5
>        host: localhost
>
> test: &test
>        adapter: postgresql
>        encoding: unicode
>        database: rentsnapper_test
>        pool: 5
>        host: localhost
>
> cucumber:
>       <<: *test