# rails server stopped working suddenly could not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Here is the error I am getting. It just stopped working suddenly

```
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
     Exiting
     /Users/JenniferAllen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@credoppl/gems/activerecord-          3.2.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1208:in `initialize': could     not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::Error)
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Did you try the steps outlined in [this question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918523/postgres-just-randomly-stopped-working-rails-pgsql-5432?rq=1). Seems to be a similar issue