# PostqreSQL in Rails: How do I make the server run locally AND accept connections on the Unix domain socket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

So I'm a newbie to Rails who's only used SQLite3 before, and I'm struggling to even run a simple rake command when using PostgreSQL.

I'm just trying to follow the first 5 minutes of this screencast on installing Postgres: http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

But even when I've done everything as instructed, when I run `rake db:create:all` I get the ubiquitous error message:

```
could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I see this everywhere, but can someone answer this definitively, once and for all (if such a task were so simple)?

I used homebrew to install PostgreSQL.

When I run `which psql`, it says i'm using the one in `usr/bin/psql`, which I believe is the one that is native to Mac OSX Lion (isn't that a bad thing? How do I switch to the one installed by homebrew, which is in `usr/local/bin/psql`?).

I'm fairly certain Postgres is at least running: when I run `ps auxw | grep postgres`, I get my four processes, such as:

```
postgres: stats collector process
postgres: autovacuum launcher process
postgres: wal writer process
postgres: writer process
```

And I was even able to install my `pg` gem just fine. I've been spending all day just trying to get Postgres to run, I appreciate any and all help!

EDIT (WITH SOLUTION):

Referencing this link:

[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

There was indeed a path issue. So I edited my .bash_profile as instructed, and switched from using my native psql installation in `usr/bin/psql` to the one installed by homebrew, `usr/local/bin/psql`.

Then, I uninstalled my pg gem, and then reinstalled it, and then rake dr:create:all started working. :)

EDIT 2:

Actually, I'm still having loads of problems! This is so frustrating! :)

Comment: cd into /var/pgsql_socket/ and then type ls -l. What does it say?

Comment: it says permission denied, if i did it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your permissions are probably messed up. Try

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/pgsql_socket/
```

This gives open permissions to everyone, so it's fine for your development server needs.

Now it should work.