# export PATH not working

Tags: macos, bash, unix, osx-lion

I'm trying to fix the problem asked / answered here:

[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

It suggests that I use `export` on `PATH`. However, here's what I'm getting:

```
$ which psql
/usr/bin/psql
$ export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin:$PATH
$ which psql
/usr/bin/psql
```

...I'm sincerely confused. Why is this happening?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/psql` exists, right? Otherwise, you may need to run the `hash` command to update the location of a previously known executable.

Comment: @chepner Oops put the wrong `export PATH` statement up there. Path is different, problem is still the same though.

Comment: What is the export path that you are actually using?

Comment: @chepner can you explain how to use `hash`?

Comment: Try changing your PATH to get rid of /usr/bin, and make sure that bash can still find psql in /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin.

Comment: @pinerd314159 Code please... That's what I'm already trying to do

Comment: @varatis: For efficiency's sake, Bash will remember the location it previously found an executable on the path. You can run something like `hash -d psql` to make it forget the previously-found location of `psql`, and then the next time you try to run `psql` it will re-search `$PATH`. But I don't think that's relevant here, because `which` doesn't have access to Bash's bank of remembered locations, so it always examines `$PATH` anyway.

Comment: @varatis: What happens if you run `/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/psql`? (Maybe it doesn't exist? Maybe it doesn't have its executable bit set?)

Comment: When you do this: export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin:$PATH, you're simply adding your new path to the beginning of the $PATH variable, which is a string composed of several different paths. If you want to isolate one path, you could simply do 'export PATH=export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin:'

Comment: @ruakh That's odd, it says it doesn't exist, even though I can navigate to it...

Comment: @varatis: What output do you get if you run `ls -l /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/psql`?

Comment: @ruakh no such file or directory

Comment: And if you run `ls -l /opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin/`?

Comment: @ruakh Same thing.... :(

Comment: @ruakh I've answered my original problem though, how to get the solution to the problem I posted above working.

Comment: @varatis: You must have a typo or something. You said you can navigate to that directory. What output do you get if you navigate there and type `pwd`?

Comment: @ruakh Ah yeah typo... It was 90 instead of 91

Comment: `which which`? Use `type` to examine Bash's PATH.

Comment: Following up on @varatis's post, see http://bradconte.com/bash-path-hashing.html for an explanation of how `bash` caches executable paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked the best for solving this immediate issue was using

```
export PATH=export PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin:
```

But please note.. this screwed up just about every other command -- it really just solved the immediate issue (that the path wasn't getting updated). I don't think this is a great long term solution, and other answers are much appreciated.

On another note, specifying the host solves the problem for the question linked to above:

`psql -h localhost -U postgres`

Comment: Why would you use illegal syntax and zap the old PATH?