# How can i setup the path for heroku postgresql app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, osx-mountain-lion, pg

I just installed the heroku PSQL app (v1.0) and i'm having trouble being able to connect my rails apps using the gem pg "0.1.4". I already added the path PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH" to my .profile and my .bashrc files, but nothing seems to allow me to run psql simply by calling "psql". I had success using "psql -h localhost". When i go for "psql" i get:

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I'm using mountain lion.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, I've been struggling for a few hours

Comment: Same problem - path isn't working. My .bashrc has the same PATH as Diego and it isn't being loaded. If I run "source .bashrc" then "which psql" it returns the correct version"/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql" however if I start a new terminal window it returns this: "/usr/bin/psql"
What is the deal here? the app installs properly, can be used, but won't load from PATH.

Comment: Is this the issue? http://nextmarvel.net/blog/2011/09/brew-install-postgresql-on-os-x-lion/

Comment: What's the result of the commands "which psql" "ls -la ~/" and "echo $PATH" ?

Answer (score 12):

Still pretty sure that both of the existing answers are answering the wrong question. The author mentions right in the title that he is having trouble with **PATH**, not connecting to his DB or configuring rails. This is the situation I got into, and this is my solution.

After getting postgres.app running and setting **PATH** in my .bashrc file as directed in the postgress.app documentation - http://postgresapp.com/documentation :

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

The problem was that this path setting was not taking effect after restarting terminal.app - running which psql was returning the copy in "/usr/bin/psql", this is the copy that comes installed with Lion and Mountain Lion, not the new version installed in "/Applications/". It even says in the Postgres.app instructions "run which psql to tell that the correct version is being loaded".

Anyway - the odd thing I found was that after I ran:

```
source .bashrc
```

Then the command "which psql" would return the correct version located in /Applications/.

At this point I was stumped and had to get some extra help. The guys I tapped also thought it was quite odd too, however they quickly found out that **neither the .bashrc OR the .profile files were being loaded.** This is very strange, I have not seen this on any of my other macs running leopard through lion.

**Now finally the solution-** I am not sure this is proper, but it did permanently fix my problem. We found that their was one profile file being loaded into the terminal - the **.bash_login** file. In the end the solution was just to use the .bash_login to source the .bashrc file. Here is the edit to .bash_login:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

And that did it.

Anyway I can't say that this is exactly the fix that diego needed / was looking for, but it is definitely the problem for me.

Comment: You can also just add PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH" to .bash_login.

Comment: or to .bash_profile, which reloads everytime you restart your console

Comment: If you know what you're doing, simply add `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` to your bash path

Comment: Nick in my case none of these files are being loaded when I start iTerm.app..
How can I found out what is being loaded ?

Comment: The documentation is wrong.  Change "Postgres.app" to "Postgres93.app"

Comment: Seems that the path has changed: See http://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html. It should be /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add `host:localhost` to any database configuration you're using in your development environment (read development / test/ production / etc):

**config/database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_awesome_app_development
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: my_awesome_app_development
  password:
```

Edit: also see [Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

Comment: He is looking for help with postgres.app PATH settings, not configuring a rails app.

Comment: @Nick: no he is not. The frontend just fails to find the unix-domain postgres-socket, which acts as a *rendez-vous* point. This is an OSX-related installation problem. (there have been several of these)

Comment: I am getting the same error as the OP, and hardcoding the host, like in this answer, does solve my problem. On the other hand, I need a solution that doesn't require me to do that, because that's how the work development environment is setup, and so I'm looking for alternatives. I've tried setting the `PGHOST=locahost` in `.bash_profile` and I found that has worked in some cases...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I just had the same problem.  The issue is that there is a typo in the documentation.  The app is Postgres93.app, not Postgres.app, so the path should have Postgres93.app:

`PATH="/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"`

It's amazing how many posts there are about this and the typo doesn't seem to have been noticed yet.  Changing that was all it took to get `psql` and `which psql` to work correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH might be wrong. To find out the PATH of your psql script (on mac) open the sql shell script from your finder in Applications/Postgres installation. This will give you a hint as to where it is installed. That opened a window which told me it is located here: /Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/scripts/runpsql.sh

Then, I set the PATH variable from the terminal window by typing:
$ PATH="/Library/PostgreSQL/8.4/bin:$PATH"