# postgres.app installed but which psql displays /usr/bin/psql and not path entered into zshrc

Tags: postgresql, osx-mountain-lion, zshrc

Having an issue with postgres.app where its installed, its running, but when I enter
    which psql
I then receive "/usr/bin/psql" and not the correct path that postgres.app expects.
When I echo my PATH I get the following:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql:/Users/username/.rvm/bin
```

As you can see its in my Path but I have no idea why it wont choose the correct psql. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `psql` is both in `/usr/bin` and `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin`, the one in `/usr/bin` will be preferred according to your `PATH` specification. Consider putting the `/Applications/...` entry before `/usr/bin`:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:...
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for your help.
Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: should now be export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit /etc/paths and make sure /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin is on the top.  More info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6772559/2643002