# Can't install rmagick gem on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

Note: my situation is almost identical to this: [Can't install pg gem on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273815/cant-install-pg-gem-on-mountain-lion).

I just upgraded from Snow Leopard to Mountain Lion and Rails is giving me all kinds of problems, especially trying to install the 'rmagick' gem. I'm running Ruby 1.9.3-p362 and Rails 3.2.11.

```
➜  git:(master) ✗ sudo gem install rmagick -v 2.13.1
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc-4.2... yes
checking for Magick-config... yes

Warning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.
         /opt/local/bin/Magick-config reports version 6.6.6 Q8 is installed in /opt/local
         /OPT/LOCAL/BIN/Magick-config reports version 6.6.6 Q8 is installed in /opt/local
         /USR/LOCAL/BIN/Magick-config reports version 6.8.0 Q16 is installed in /USR/LOCAL/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10
Using 6.6.6 Q8 from /opt/local.

checking for ImageMagick version >= 6.4.9... yes
checking for HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
/Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:368:in `try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:452:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:834:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:693:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:276:in `postpone'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:692:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:833:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:193:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/sscirrus/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

➜  applyco git:(master) ✗ brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Error: imagemagick-6.8.0-10 already installed

➜  applyco git:(master) ✗ apt-get install libmagick9-dev
zsh: command not found: apt-get
```

I have tried:

- Installing Xcode with command line tools
- Reinstalling homebrew
- Clearing out all my repo's gems (including Gemfile.lock) and running `bundle install`
- Reinstalling the bundler gem
- Reinstalling ImageMagick

Nothing, including answers elsewhere on SO, have been of any use. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am going through the same issue here... But one difference, maybe your homebrew its linked to another version of Imagemagick.

So even though imagemagick-6.8.0-10 is installed is not being found.

Try something like `brew unlink imagemagick` then `brew link imagemagick` and see what happens.
Have your tried `brew doctor` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you setting up my dev environment on Mountain Lion for RoR 3.2.11.  Apparently the last version of RMagick (2.13.1 ) doesn't play nice compiling with the last version of ImageMagick (6.8.2-0). Disabling openmp and building from source worked like, ahem.. Magick.

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp --build-from-source
gem install rmagick
```

I didn't need to edit the brew formula described in http://blog.paulopoiati.com/2013/01/28/installing-rmagick-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/, but that would be the next step to try.

Answer (score 1):

I am going through the same issue here...
But one difference, maybe your homebrew its linked to another version of Imagemagick.

So even though imagemagick-6.8.0-10 is installed is not being found.

Try something like
`brew unlink imagemagick`
then `brew link imagemagick`
and see what happens.

This fixed my problem
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion

Answer (score 1):

It may be a permissions issue try running

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```

and then try again.

Comment: This should be the validated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while trying to use Paperclip with Rails 3 for the first time.
Just to sum up previous answers, what worked for me was the following:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
brew link --overwrite imagemagick
```

Thanks!