# Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

While running bundle install i am getting the following error in 'pg' gem i changed the gem as sqlite then too am getting same error. This is my error message.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.16.0/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried `apt-get install libpg-dev` `gem install pg -v '0.16.0'` nothing helps me

Comment: it should be a dev package missing, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645918/require-no-such-file-to-load-mkmf-loaderror) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731904/rails-installation-failed-on-ubuntu-with-cannot-load-such-file-mkmf)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767725/unable-to-install-gem-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-cannot-load-such

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816331/geminstallerextensionbuilderror-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem i solved it by installing it in `ubuntu` as normal user not as `root user`. I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 14):

You should have postgresql installed before you install pg gem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev
```

If your sqlite is not working, it looks like there are some packages you might have missed.

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev libssl-dev zlib1g-dev build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev
```

Comment: For sqlite, did you install the dependencies? I will update the answer with dependencies

Comment: I am not sure about sqlite dependencies but for postgresql i installed everything and its working in command line. But i am unable to locate gem.

Comment: The dependencies I have given is not restricted to sqlite. It also includes packages other than sqlite. Try installing the packages I have given, it should work.

Comment: Its throwing same error. I tried most of the Stackoverflow answers.

Comment: you tried this one `sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev` and then reinstalling the gems?

Comment: Here are the updated instructions on how to install postgress http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Comment: Installing those dependencies worked for me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu 14.04 (and possibly every other Debian 7 based distro) this problem is caused by the absence of the Ruby development package. Thus the fix is simply to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Comment: `sudo yum install ruby-devel` for CentOS (solved my issue)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by follwing these steps

1. Uninstalled ruby completely using `sudo apt-get purge ruby*`
2. Then in removed curl `sudo apt-get purge curl`

Then i followed this link to install Ruby RVM and rails 4.0.0

[Install Rails 4.0.0](http://railsapps.github.io/installing-rails.html)

Answer (score 1):

Install

```
http://postgresapp.com/
```

then

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

then

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to update your Ruby library, run this code:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with slightly different Ruby builds. The existing application's `Gemfile.lock` was created using `ruby-1.9.3-p194` and my local ruby was `ruby-1.9.3-p484`. Switching to the proper ruby allowed for a successful bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with CentOS 6.5.

1. Created a new user
2. Added this users to the sudoers file /etc/sudoers
3. Install ruby-devel using `yum -y install ruby-devel`

Answer (score 0):

On Debian, the `pg` install was failing to build native extensions because postgres wasn't installed.

I installed the postgres dependencies with:

```
$ apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client libpq-dev
```

Then the `pg` gem built its dependencies just fine:

```
$ gem install pg -v '0.18.3'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-0.18.3
1 gem installed
```