# `require': Incorrect MySQL client library version

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, scaffolding

When I run rails server it shows errors message like this:

```
`require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.1.42. (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
        from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
        from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
        from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
        from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
        from C:/Rails/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
```

I installed Mysql 5.1 database.

In my gem file I wrote this:

```
gem 'mysql'
```

then run bundle install

What causes this problem?

Comment: mysql is a very old gem, try with mysql2

Comment: @apneadiving , when installing mysql2 gem , got the fallowing error.Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: heres a question about that error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816331/geminstallerextensionbuilderror-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension ,

Answer (score 2):

try this out

add in you Gemfile

```
 gem 'mysql2'
```

and then do bundle install, and run this command at the command line to install these packages.

```
   sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

on windows

> copy libmysql.dll from mysql installation folder to your Ruby bin
>   directory on your system.

Comment: Is there any command equivalent to sudo, Mine is windows Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try including mysql2 gem instead, in your gemfile just add:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Comment: when installing mysql2 gem , got the fallowing error.Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Comment: @SanjaySahu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051448/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-mysql2-on-rails-3-2-3