# PSQL on Mac OS X Lion Permanent Solution?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, homebrew, psql

I keep getting this error when I try to do stuff with psql:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I tried the fix in the first answer to this question: [Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

That resolves the problem, but when I close and reopen Homebrew, the problem appears again, i.e. "which psql" outputs /usr/bin/psql. Any ideas?