# PATH issue installing Postgres on OS X Lion: How do I edit Bash_Profile?

Tags: ruby, bash, postgresql, unix, homebrew

I'm trying to get Postgres up and running on OS X Lion - homebrew - rvm.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

After following the above instructions, I ran into the same problem described here:

[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

Running `which psql` yields `usr/bin/psql` when it should be `usr/local/bin/psql`

Ok, I understand that I need to edit my bash file with `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

There's a ton of questions on here mentioning this is what I should do.

**UPDATE**

Here's what I tried:

I opened up the .bash_file this way:

```
open -e ~/.bash_profile
```

And modified it like this (this is all that is in the file):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "/Users/chase/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/chase/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Running `source ~/.bash_profile` then `which psql` now yields `usr/local/bin/psql`

Which seems to have answered the main question.

However, when I go generate a new rails app with `-d postgresql` as the database, it works up until I try `rake db:create:all` which results in

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

But I suppose that's for another question ; )

[Postgres - could not connect to server after trying rake db:create:all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508075/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server-after-trying-rake-dbcreateall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bash file is located in your home directory `~/.bash_profile`. Use any editor to modify it.

You can enter `nano ~/.bash_profile` in the terminal if you don't have an editor set up, and it will open a simple editor in the terminal to enable you to edit the file. It will do the job, but everybody should really switch to a better editor.

There you have to change the order of the `export PATH` elements. Just put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` so the shell will check the `/usr/local/bin` first.

Answer (score 2):

Your `.bash_profile` file is in your home directory. If the file isn't there, just make one.

Terminal windows should open in your home directory. You can also get there by typing `cd ~`. Or open the file from a Finder window, but it'll be invisible unless you've selected to "Show Hidden Files".

As far as *how* to edit it, use whatever editor you're comfortable with, but make sure it can save actual text files (e.g., no rich text a la Word, OpenOffice, etc unless you export as plain text).