# Postgres - could not connect to server after trying rake db:create:all

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, unix, homebrew, postgres.app

I'm trying to get Postgres up and running on OS X Lion - homebrew - rvm.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

After following the above instructions, I ran into the same problem described here:

[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

Running `which psql` yieled `usr/bin/psql` when it should be `usr/local/bin/psql`

Ok, so I modified the path like this (this is all that is in the file):

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "/Users/chase/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/Users/chase/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Good - running `source ~/.bash_profile` then `which psql` now yields `usr/local/bin/psql`

***However***, when I go generate a new rails app with `-d postgresql` as the database, it works up until I try `rake db:create:all` which results in

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any clue?

**UPDATE**

I ended up installing the Postgres.app: http://postgresapp.com/ - this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://postgresapp.com defines itself as "The easiest way to get started with PostgreSQL on the Mac. Just download, drag to the applications folder, and double-click". It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this and using Postgres.app, you may need host: localhost in your database.yml. http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_3