# How to properly edit path in .profile

Tags: python, profile, psql

Everytime I try to run psql on my mac 10.8 I get the error message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion) on the problem it's a PATH issue.

I tried editing my path by opening my .profile and adding the line: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

However, when I do `which psql` it still shows `/usr/bin/psql`.

Why isn't it showing the proper path I want: `/usr/local/bin/psql` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you restarted your shell since editing your `.profile`?

Are you sure that `/usr/local/bin/psql` exists and has the correct permissions?

Are you sure that you're using `bash`? (You can type `echo $0` at the shell prompt to see.) If your shell is `tcsh` then you'd need to add this line to `~/.tcshrc` or `~/.cshrc` instead. What would be even easier, though, would be to add this to your `~/.login`:

```
setenv PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

That will make sure that the changes take effect no matter which shell you use.

Comment: Yes I have restarted it and it says I'm using bash. But `/usr/local/bin/psql` does not exist.

Comment: Are you installing psql with Homebrew? Try running `brew doctor` to check your setup, and if necessary, uninstall and reinstall the package.

Comment: I didn't install with Homebrew... Just downloaded from the web: http://postgresapp.com/ and then ran the installer.

Comment: Ah. In that case, the path to `psql` should be `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql`. You can just add `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: Ok just say I already have this in my path `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`.... How exactly should I add it (sorry for the noobness of this question).

Comment: No problem :-) Just change that line to `export PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`