# Can't rake db:setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to setup up a small practice ruby on rails project with Postgres.

Here's the link if anyone wants to know what I'm following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-setup-ruby-on-rails-with-postgres

The thing is that every time I try to do either `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:setup`, I get this error: (this has been shortened to this)

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

My current version of Postgress is `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.2`

The path for it via Homebrew is this: `/usr/local/bin/psql` which is correct according to this link:[Repairing Postgresql after upgrading to OSX 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770649/repairing-postgresql-after-upgrading-to-osx-10-7-lion)

Also, this is my bash info:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
```

Is there any other information I need to include to get this working?

Thank you.

**edit**

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On OS X with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On OS X with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password:

 # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
 # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
 # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
 #host: localhost

 # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
 # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
 #port: 5432

 # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
 #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

 # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
 #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
 #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
 # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

 # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
 # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
 # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
   test:
     adapter: postgresql
     encoding: unicode
     database: myapp_test
     pool: 5
     username: myapp
    password:

   production:
     adapter: postgresql
     encoding: unicode
     database: myapp_production
     pool: 5
     username: myapp
    password:
```

Comment: did you configure the database correctly? it seems that you can not connect to the database. maybe it is not running.

Comment: @wkaha, how do I know if i configured it correctly?

Comment: @wkaha, how do you connect to it?

Comment: use config/database.yml to configure. you may add it to your question

Comment: @devanand, have added my database.yml info

Comment: add a host: localhost and a port: 5432 it may helps. you are able to connect vita psql command?

Comment: @devanand, how do i connect it via psql command?

Comment: @devanand, add a host? you mean to the yml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Is the server running locally`?

Make sure you've started the postgres server and have it running. If you're on a mac, the easiest way to do this is to use Postgres.app: [postgresapp.com](http://postgresapp.com/)

By default the server will run on port 5432.

Also, ensure `localhost` is in your database configuration:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  host: localhost
```

`username` and `password` can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to start your postgres server.

Here is the official documentation that postgres has on how to start the server.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/server-start.html

Also, make sure that you've created the appropriate user and database for your app.
If you followed the tutorial you linked to the letter, you'll have a user `myapp` with a password `password1`.